# iOS get which uielement invoked UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

Tags: ios, ios5, uielement

In my iOS app I have several `UIElement`s that can process user input: textfields, editable webviews, etc. each time I write something into these `UIElement`s the keyboard (obviously) will come up. Before it happens I can catch this event by observing the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

I would like to know what's the way to find out which `UIElement` invoked this action.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard is launched when the view tapped by a user is set as FirstResponder, so I think this question is the equivalent of saying [how do I get the current first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone) when UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is received?.

The [answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823360/925478) by Thomas Muller was to use a class extension along the lines of:

```
@implementation UIView (FindFirstResponder)
- (UIView *)findFirstResponder
{
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {        
        return self;     
    }

    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        UIView *firstResponder = [subView findFirstResponder];

        if (firstResponder != nil) {
            return firstResponder;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
@end
```

So I think you could use that inside your handler for UIKeyboardWillShow to figure out what caused it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the section 4 (Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard) of this document can give you a hint about knowing wich element has the keyboard.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1

Comment: In the link the use UIKeyboardDidShow notification, @zoltan was asking about getting the responder on UIKeyboardWillShow notification