# Hiding the UIKeyboard

Tags: objective-c, uikeyboard

I am trying to hide the keyboard in my SplitView application (because it covers over part of the root menu).  However, the only thing I can find is how to hide the keyboard after a textfield has been used `[TextField resignFirstResponder]`.

Is there any other way to hide the keyboard?
Ideally I would like to use the barButtonItem, which displays the menu, as a trigger to hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the `-resignFirstResponder` message to the instance of whatever UI element currently has first responder status. So if there were a `firstNameTextField` property on your class that corresponds to an instance of `UITextField`, you need to send the message to that object.

`[self.firstNameTextField resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: Does it work with any UI element?  Can I use a UIBarButtonItem?  My whole problem is that I don't have a specific textfield to link it to.

Comment: Technically any instance of `UIView` can become the first responder since it is a subclass of `UIResponder` but it only invokes the keyboard if the class conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol. To dismiss the keyboard via a `UIBarButtonItem`, you need to connect that button to a method that invokes `resignFirstResponder` on the active text field. If you just want to blindly end all editing, you can also send `endEditing:` to the root view and it will walk through the subviews and resign first responder on which ever subview currently has it.

Answer (score 0):

`resignFirstResponder` is way to do it. If you have a situation where your firstResponder is not set up as an instance variable (perhaps its generated), you can 'get' your firstResponder using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823360/442328). After you have your first responder object, simply resign it!

hope this helps.