# How to delete an item from UICollectionView with indexpath.row

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view,and I tried to delete a cell from collection view on didSelect method.I succeeded in that using the following method

```
  [colleVIew deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
```

But now I need to delete the item on button click from CollectionView Cell.Here I get only the indexpath.row.
From this I am not able to delete the Item.
I tried like this.

```
-(void)remove:(int)i {

    NSLog(@"index path%d",i);
   [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];

   NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
   [colleVIew deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
    [colleVIew reloadData];
  }
```

But it needs to reload the CollectionView.So the animation of cell arrangement after deletion is not there.
Please suggest an idea..thanks in advance

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
-(void)remove:(int)i {

    [self.collectionObj performBatchUpdates:^{
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [self.collectionObj deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Try this. It may work for you.

Comment: Thanks...It is help me and save my time.

Comment: The key to this problem that this answer addresses is both the item to remove from the array and the item to delete from the collectionView **both occur inside** `performBatchUpdates`

Answer (score 21):

Swift 3 solution:

```
func remove(_ i: Int) {

    myObjectsList.remove(at: i)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)

    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    }) { (finished) in
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
    }

}
```

and example delete call:

```
self.remove(indexPath.row)
```

Answer (score 5):

swift 3:

```
func remove(index: Int) {
    myObjectList.remove(at: index)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    }, completion: {
        (finished: Bool) in
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [collection reloadData]; // Collection is UICollectionView
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

`[array removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];`

`[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];`

Normally it's ok... You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894172/deleting-cells-from-uicollectionview-via-nsnotification), it deals with same subject.

Comment: but I am not getting the indexpath

I assigns i = indexpath.row;

Comment: @NithinMK you have to assign the indexpath for getting the reference of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer..

Create a button in CollectionViewCell // I named it as removeBtn

Then in CollectionView Delegate

```
 - cellForItemAtIndexPath

   [cell.removeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(RemovePrssd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then add the method

```
-(void)RemovePrssd:(id)sender{

 UIView *senderButton = (UIView*) sender;
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [colleVIew indexPathForCell: (UICollectionViewCell *)[[senderButton superview]superview]];

  [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [colleVIew deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is which `IndexPath` you choose.

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
      NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
     [self.datas removeObjectAtIndex:currentIndexPath.row];
     [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[currentIndexPath]];
} completion:nil];
```