# Delete Cell from UICollectionView Without Reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, indexpath

My app is listening to a socket event which tells it when there's been an update to the data which is currently being displayed by the `collectionView` on screen. When this occurs I'd like to remove the cell corresponding to the updated row from the data source, and from the `collectionView`. I can do this as follows:

1. filter the data to contain only items with an id different to the id of the updated item
2. set this new data to be the data used by the `collectionView`
3. reload the `collectionView`

   ```
   socket.on(DATA_UPDATE) { (data, ack) in
          if let dat = data[0] as? [String: Any] {
             if let tabId = dat["tabId"] as? Int, let resId = dat["resId"] as? Int {
                let remainingData = self.data?.filter{ $0.tabId != tabId }
                if resId == self.restaurant?.id && remainingData?.count != self.data?.count {
                    self.data = remainingData
                    self.filterTableDataAndRelaod()
                }
             }
          }
       }
   ```

The problem with this is that it updates the whole `collectionView` and also scrolls up to the top. I wanted to do this using the following code instead:

```
self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
```

However, I'm not sure how to obtain the `indexPath` in the above code snippet.

Comment: use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297327/4833705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 var toDele = [IndexPath]()
    if let tabId = dat["tabId"] as? Int, let resId = dat["resId"] as? Int {
       for (index,item) in self.data?.enumerated() {
           if item.tabId == tabId {
              toDele.append(IndexPath(item:index,section:0)) 
           }
        } 

        for item in toDele {
            self.data?.remove(at:item.item)
        }
       collectionView.deleteItems(at:toDele )
  }
```

or if you don't have duplicates

```
   if let tabId = dat["tabId"] as? Int, let resId = dat["resId"] as? Int {
       if let ind = self.data?.firstIndex(where:{ $0.tabId == tabId }) {
            self.data?.remove(at:ind) 
            collectionView.deleteItem(at:IndexPath(item:ind,section:0))
       }
   }
```