# How to know who isFirstResponder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Very beginner **obj-c** question.

Is it a possibility to ask about who is first responder at the moment? I have a tableView with four custom cells and with `textfield` in every cell. [Link](http://uaimage.com/image/62f08045)

I tagged `textFields` from 1 to 4. And I need to realise the possibility of switching between `textfields` with buttons '**Next**' and '**Previous**' . So ,for example, in code of button '**Next**' I need something like this:

```
    if ([[txtfld.tag == 1] isFirstResponder) 
    {
     [[txtfld.tag == 2] becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

But this code isn't worked because I don't know how to call **textField** from method where it's not visible. Is it a right way of thinking to resolve this problem, or maybe there is a better approach?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get reference to your `UITableViewCell` and then you can use the `-viewWithTag` method. For example `UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];`

Then you can check `[textField isFirstResponder];`

Comment: What do you mean to get reference? To set property or set delegate?