# Custom UITableViewCell with canBecomeFirstResponder YES won't deselect when offscreen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I recently happend to find some interesting bug in UITableView regarding selection and deselection functionality. (m.b. it's not a bug per se, but I find this situation very abnormous).

Prehistory: I was trying to create some custom TableViewCell class that will be able to use UIDatePicker to pick some date and place it in cell's label. The ["CellDate" sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) is not very good for me. So I was trying to set some custom inputView to cell and make it first responder. After some time of researches I found the way to override readonly inputView property of my custom UITableViewCell subclass, and now it works perfectly: when the cell is selected I call `[self becomeFirstResponder]` on it and when the cell is deselected I call `[self resignFirstResponder]` so it works just fine, but there is some bug.

When I have my custom cell on screen (i.e. not scrolled out off screen) everything is correct, but if I select it

[image: Selecting custom cell]

scroll tableView down so my cell is no longer on screen

[image: Scrolled down, custom cells are no longer on screen]

and then select some another cell

[image: Selecting some other cell while custom cell is no longer on screen]

my custom cell won't be deselected

[image: Unexcpected result].

The only main change in default UITableViewCell's functionality is this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if (selected)
    {
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

using just this method overrides makes this bug to appear: when currently selected custom cell is offscreen it won't deselect for some reason.

My question is: did anyone experience something like this and is there anything I can do? Because apart from this I have a perfect solution for my problem of date cell.

Is that not a correct way to work with UITableViewCells? Am I doing something completely wrong? I'm just starting to learn iOS, so I'm maybe not very familiar with some of it's aspects.

P.S. sorry for my bad language, I'm not a native English speaker.

UPDATE:

I've found out some more details. After some research I figured out, that when you scroll your tableView and hide some tableViewCell offscreen it's (cell) is being destroyed. And when you scroll back it is being created again via call to tableView's delegate's tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
Apart from this if you will try to call [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] for indexPath of row, that is being offscreen, tableView will return you a nil.

But the strange thing is: when your custom cell is being firstResponder, apparently, it won't be recreated via tableView's delegate's tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and it won't be accessible via [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] neither.

As for me, that's very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution by myself. It appears to be as simple as resigning first responder when other row is being selected. By the way, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api) to accomplish this.

Hope it could help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question, the UITableView does not deselect cells on it's own. In your TableView's controller, you need to override `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and manually deselect the selected cell.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animate:YES];
}
```

(apologies for editing, i accidentally saved while answering)

In your subclass of the UITableViewCell you should override `-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` in order to transition your cells into an editable state. (set your UITextField to editable) and then in your cell, you would make your textbox become/resign first responder.

First responder is used to become the next object to respond to the keyboard when something is editable.

For example, if you have cell c1, and cell c2. both c1 and c2 have UITextFields in them. You are in c1, and you want the Return button in the keyboard to move the text cursor into c2, then when c1, would need to make the UITextField resign as the first responder, and tell c2 to make it's UITextField become the first responder.
You would do this by making the custom cell be the delegate of it's UITextField, then implement `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` to have the textField resign as first responder, then you would tell your UITableView's controller to tell the next cell to make it's textfield become first responder.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
The default tableView behavior, as I can see, is deselecting previously selected cell when selecting some other cell. I'll try to override tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, but it seems to me like default behavior is corrupted.

Comment: Also, am I actually have to use UITextField? It's not actually what I want to use, because I don't have text field per se in my cell, the whole cell is a control element which changes it's label content according to selected date. And I'm not interested in editing state of UITableViewCell neither, because cell won't suppose to change its state. The only thing I require right now is correct work of select/deselect of cells

Comment: It seems as if I have found some more details, I'll update question