# removing keyboard from Screen without calling resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I have a custom View (`NotifyView`) added on `UIWindow` with a dismiss button(which remove it from `UIWindow`).
This view is added when a PUSH notification comes in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`
there are several cases when I could be on any screen, and my keyboard is UP via `UITextfield`/`UITextview`.
At this stage if a push comes, the `NotifyView` is added on `UIWindow` behind the keyboard.
I want to resign the keyboard once the PUSH is received so for that I could:

- post a Notification with `NSNotificaitonCenter` to resign all textfields/textviews (if anyone is `firstResponder`). For this I have to keep active pointer to the currently active textfield/textview in all controllers.
- make a variable in AppDelegate and assign the active textfields/textviews to it and on PUSH, and `resignFirstResponder` of those on PUSH.

Both of the solutions would require making changes to all controller's code and I am looking for something more generic like:

- could there be any way through which I could simply remove the Keyboard from the screen on receiving PUSH
- or I could fetch the current firstResponder of the application and resign it explicitly.

these could be generic solutions.

It would be really helpful if someone could facilitate this thought process or someone have any immediate solution for this case.

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the method below

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try  this one , for me it works fine 
`[yourView endEditing:YES]`

Comment: i am looking for one more step generic as for this I have maintain track of my current view to call this.

Comment: Called to this method will actually call `resignFirstResponder` if there's UITextField in the view. 

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting

Answer (score 0):

The problem it is, when you want to give back the focus.

I have implemented as listening each textfield and caching which is the latest. Than resign only that one ( in push ) after that restore state, require focus for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in delegate method...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  [self.view endEditing:YES]; // added this in for case when keyboard was already on screen
  [self editStartDate:textField];
  return NO;
}
```