# textViewDidBeginEditing - determining which text box is being edited

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a page with 5 `UITextView` objects. I use the `textViewDidBeginEditing:` method to animate the `observationComment` text box which works fine. But now I want to do the same for the other 4, but I can't seem to work out how to determine which text view has been tapped. The `observationComment` textbox fires each time I click on any of the others.

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *) observationComment
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:observationComment];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    obsCommentLabel.frame= CGRectMake(192, 113, 148, 21);
    observationComment.frame=CGRectMake(191, 135, 710, 250);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. You have 5 UITextViews and 5 UILabels? And you want know which label belongs to the text view that was just clicked?

Comment: Yes but we can ignore the labels. The problem is that I have one UITextView is called observationComment. When I click inside this text view the animations work fine. Now I have added 4 more UITextViews and I would like to set different animations for each of them, however when I click on any of them the observationComment frame animates. I am trying to work out how to distinguish between the different UITextViews from within the textViewDidBeginEditing method.

Comment: I believe this might be your best bet

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api

Answer (score 1):

The object passed to the delegate method is generic so like you say, it will be used for all text views.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

To tell the text views apart you either need to keep a reference to the UITextView's (IBOutlet or otherwise) as a property and then compare `textView` to those properties or alternatively, set the tag property on each UITextView to unique integers and check the tags to tell which is which. Using

```
#define OBSERVATION_COMMENT_TAG 1001
```

and then checking `OBSERVATION_COMMENT_TAG` makes your code more readable than hard coding the tag constants within the code. To reference the tag from within the -textViewDidBeginEditing: delegate method, you would use the `tag` property on the view itself

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSInteger tag = [textView tag];
    switch (tag) {
        case OBSERVATION_COMMENT_TAG:
        {
            // observation comment text view
            break;
        }
        case ADDITIONAL_TEXTVIEW_TAG:
        {
            // additional text view
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added tags to each of the text boxes but can't seem to workout how to reference the tags from within the textViewDidBeginEditing method.

Comment: I've updating my answer showing how to reference the tags in the delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the following solution, but it will work for your conditions:

YourViewController.h:

```
UITextView *tv1, *tv2, *tv3, *tv4, *tv5;
```

YourViewController.m:

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)observationComment
{
    if (observationComment == tv1)
        // animation 1
    else if (observationComment == tv2)
        // animation 2
    ... and so on ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags solution worked perfectly:

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing: (UITextView *) obsComment
{
if (obsComment.tag == 1)
{
... animations
}
else if (obsComment.tag == 2)
{
... animations
}
```

Thanks for everyone's advice and help.