# Dismissing keyboard on iPad from textfield inside tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, uipopovercontroller

I have a problem with the iOS keyboard. I have a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell. When tapping on another TableViewCell within the same TableView, I want to dismiss the keyboard before showing a UIPopoverController. All of this is shown in a form sheet.

Here is the view hierarchy:

- Root View Controller

  - `UINavigationController`, shown as `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`

    - Table View Controller

      - Table View Cell 1

        - Text Field
      - Table View Cell 2

        - When tapped: `UIPopoverController` containing a `UIDatePicker`

In this graph, I want to add code in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to dismiss the keyboard just before showing the `UIPopoverController`. This is not a problem on iPhone as I use a fullscreen modal view controller instead of a popover controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // nameTextField is the text field in Table View Cell 1
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];

    UITextField *tempTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 10)];
    [self.view addSubview:tempTextField];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    tempTextField.enabled = NO;
    [tempTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [tempTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [tempTextField removeFromSuperview];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    KDDatePickerViewController *dpvc = [[KDDatePickerViewController alloc] init];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:dpvc];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

As you can see from the code, I tried calling `resignFirstResponder` and `endEditing`, and I tried to create a temporary text field.
I also tried implementing `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`, but it was never called.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual problem? You never say what is going wrong, just what you have tried.

Comment: is `nameTextField` the field you are refering to in Table View Cell 1? do you have other textfields textviews in the view?

Comment: @maddy: The keyboard does not get dismissed when displaying the popover controller. I am trying to force the text field to lose focus, but the keyboard stays.

Comment: @KDaker Sorry, I forgot to mention that. You're right, nameTextField is the textfield in the table view cell 1. I do not have other textfields or textviews in my tableview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[nameTextField resignFirstResponder]` should be sufficient. It could be that the IBOutlet isn't binding correctly or there is something else that is the first responder.

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823360/442328) to dismiss the current first responder. If this does work, however, I would suggest you still look into the issue of why it isn't dismissing when you reference it directly.

I would suggest removing `tempTextField` before trying this.

The answer I linked is helpful and you can use it but it is more appropriate in a case where you have several TextFields and you don't necessarily know which is the first responder.

hope this helps

**Update**

according to [apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`:

> The default implementation of this method returns YES when the modal
>   presentation style of       the view controller is set to
>   UIModalPresentationFormSheet and returns NO for other presentation
>   styles. Thus, the system normally does not allow the keyboard to be
>   dismissed for modal forms.

so simply override it in your controller and return `NO`

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that after calling `[nameTextField resignFirstResponder]` the blinking cursor disappeared. So I think the text field has actually lost focus, but for some reason the keyboard doesn't go away. I also noticed that tapping the keyboard no longer inserts text into the text field. I don't have any other text fields. I've just tried the ansert you linked to but I still had the same problem: keyboard doesn't go away, but the text field seems to lose focus and typing on the keyboard no longer inserts text.

Comment: Thank you so much! Overriding `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create random new views to try to force the keyboard. `UIView` already offers a feature. Try:

```
[tableView endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: I commented out the other code where I tried adding the temporary text field and I inserted `[tableView endEditing:YES];`, but the keyboard still doesn't get dismissed.

Comment: Possibly `[tableView.window endEditing:YES];`

Comment: That also doesn't seem to work in this case. I noticed that when using either one of your methods, or `[nameTextField resignFirstResponder];` the blinking cursor from the text field disappeared. So it seems like the text field is no longer the first responder, but for some reason the keyboard doesn't disappear.