# Class variables not yet supported

Tags: xcode, swift

I begin my project with a split view controller as initial view controller and start it automatically from storyboard.

Generally, an app with this UI have **one and only one** split view controller as root, so I create a **static variable** in the subclass and set it when initialisation was done.

So I want try this behaviour with swift.

I read the Swift programming language guide book on iBook about Type properties (with static and class keyword) and trying a piece of code to the job:

```
import UIKit

class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController {

    class func sharedInstance() -> SplitViewController {
        return SplitViewController.instance
    }

    class let instance: SplitViewController = nil

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.initialization()
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        self.initialization()
    }

    func initialization() {
        SplitViewController.instance = self;
    }
}
```

but I figured out when Xcode say the class keyword for type properties wasn't supported yet.

[image: error detail in image]

**Did you have a solution to do this ?**

Comment: What happens if you replace 'let' with 'var'?

Comment: It yields the same error.

Comment: It's the first seed, calm down. :) If the book says it's supported and it's not yet available, it **will** be. Even the error says **"yet"**.

Comment: Yes @akashivskyy you've reason but may be it could be and error on my side and someone have a solution to do this behavior...

Comment: Would just like to add that if you write static instead of class you get an error: Static properties are only allowed within structs and enums; use 'class' to declare a class property

Comment: With the Xcode 6 DP5 working around, class static properties are still not supported.

Comment: Even with the GM 'seed' release still not supported :(

Comment: This is too bad. I think this will be needed by a lot of people.

Comment: For myself, I think that's the only missing for using Swift in production...

Comment: Still "not yet supported"

Comment: Is there a reason it's not supported? Creating a structure seems to be a sort of "hack". Is there a different way to do this? Are they encouraging developers to stay away from static class variables by not supporting this? Or have they "just not gotten around to it"? Lotta questions.  It just seems like a huge thing for Apple to just include later.

Comment: @lespommes Apple is notoriously tight-lipped about anything that's pending.  It's embarrassing for them that such a standard and obvious feature was lacking from their huge release of their new flagship language.  There are many improvements required before Swift is ready for serious use.

Comment: I tried this again in Xcode 6.1.1 and it seems that this is now supported

Comment: Someone have tried in new Xcode beta and Swift 1.2, I appreciate a feedback if you have !

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Swift now has support for static variables in classes. This is not exactly the same as a class variable (because they aren't inherited by subclasses), but it gets you pretty close:

```
class X {
  static let y: Int = 4
  static var x: Int = 4
}

println(X.x)
println(X.y)

X.x = 5

println(X.x)
```

Comment: As Bill says, that's the not the same but that's I need !

Comment: @VincentSaluzzo, (and Bill) What the difference between this and class variable?

Comment: The Apple documentation have changed recently to update status : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID265

In fact, `class` keyword can only used for computed properties now and static are for all type properties (in enum, class or struct)

Comment: @skywinder As I mentioned in my answer, true class variables can be inherited by subclasses. Static variables can't.

Comment: @VincentSaluzzo Does Apple update its document? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264 look at the fourth paragraph: "For value types (that is, structures and enumerations), you can define stored and computed type properties. For classes, you can define computed type properties only."

Comment: @Bill Your answer, if talking about Swift, is wrong (at the moment of speaking). Type properties, means properties defined as static, are inherited by subclasses no matter if they are stored or computed. Stored type properties are not overridable in subclasses. Unlike stored type properties, a computed type properties are, if you use class keyword instead of static keyword.

Comment: @Whirlwind Um, I'm not making a distinction between stored and computed properties...if you read my answer and comment, I'm talking about the difference between `static` and `class` properties...

Answer (score 73):

Embedding a struct can work just fine as a workaround:

```
class SomeClass
{
  // class var classVariable: Int = 0
  // "Class variables not yet supported." Weird.

  // Workaround:
  private struct SubStruct { static var staticVariable: Int = 0 }

  class var workaroundClassVariable: Int
  {
    get { return SubStruct.staticVariable }
    set { SubStruct.staticVariable = newValue }
  }
}
```

The SomeClass.workaroundClassVariable computed type property can then be used as if it were a stored type property.

Comment: Worked for me - except as I had to drop the 'public' as XCode 6.0 did not like me declaring a public class within an internal class.

Comment: Works great, except that xcode does not allow nested type in a generic type... so if you have a generic class, it seems rather hopeless as only computed properties are possible.

Answer (score 19):

It seems to be possible to declare variables with static storage duration in file scope (as in C):

```
var sharedInstance: SplitViewController? = nil

class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
    ....
    func initialization() {
        sharedInstance = self
    }
}
```

Comment: mmmh, why not, but define a var at file scope doesn't do a memory leak in a long time usage ?

Comment: @VincentSaluzzo There's no difference to what you did before Swift: store the sole instance in a static variable. There's nothing to be leaked here, except the single instance which lives as long as the process.

Comment: I tried this in playground with my own class. It doesn't work 'cos the class has not be declared yet when you initialized that "static" var. I have not tried it in Xcode project (i guess it must have worked there?). So I may need to figure out "class forward declaration" like you always do when specifying protocol for a class.

Comment: Note that in Xcode 6.0, you cannot have two file scope variables with the same name, even if they are `private`.

Comment: @NikolayTsenkov Exactly.

Answer (score 14):

My preferred method is to just use a private file scope var outside of the class and then implement class/static getters and setters:

```
private var _classVar: Int = 0;

class SomeClass
{
    public class var classVar: Int
    {
        get { return _classVar }
        set { _classVar = newValue }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Swift 1.2 (available with Xcode 6.3b1 and onwards), `static` class properties and methods are supported.

```
class SomeClass
{
    static var someVariable: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Did you catch if they just deprecated the `class` variable, or is there a distinction (used to be `static` for structs, `class` for classes)?

Comment: @chrisco The release notes state that `static` is an alias for `class final`.

Answer (score 4):

[Using a dispatch_once singleton model in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)

Seems to be the best answer so far, avoiding the use of a global variable.

Answer (score 4):

A solution enough similar than var in file scope but more customisable and near singleton is to use a struct which support static var as property of class

```
struct PersonSharedData {
    static var backstore = ""
    var data: String {
    get { return PersonSharedData.backstore }
    set { PersonSharedData.backstore = newValue }
    }
}

class Person {
    var shared=PersonSharedData() //<< pseudo class var
    var family: String {
        get { return shared.data }
        set { shared.data=newValue }
    }
    var firstname = ""
    var lastname = ""
    var sexe: Sexe = .Unknown
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, with the solution of Nikolai that do the work. I post my changes in this thread for information

```
var instance: SplitViewController? = nil

class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController {

    class func sharedInstance() -> SplitViewController? {
        return instance;
    }

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.initialization()
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        self.initialization()
    }

    func initialization() {
        instance = self
    }
}
```

and for example, in my appDelegate, I can access this static method like this

```
SplitViewController.sharedInstance()!.presentsWithGesture = false
```

Comment: I'm just curious, but isn't the variable "instance" a global variable then? This would mean that if you have another singleton class your variable "instance" would be overwritten, right?

Answer (score 1):

The wording in the error heavily implies this will be a language feature in the future.

You may want to resort temporarily to declaring a property variable in the Application Delegate and retrieve it from there. Not ideal, definitely an anti-pattern, but would give you a central place to retrieve the `UISplitViewController` when needed.

Comment: No because in my case, the SplitViewController was initizalize by runtime when awake from storyboard, so I can't directly access to this view controller from my application delegate

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the class variables inside an inner struct variable

```
class Store{
    var name:String
    var address:String
    var lat:Int
    var long:Int
    init(name:String, address:String, lat:Int, long:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.lat = lat
        self.long=long
    }

    private struct FACTORY_INITIALIZED_FLAG { static var initialized: Bool = false
       static var  myStoreList:[Store]?
        static func getMyStoreList()->[Store]{
            if !initialized{
                println("INITIALIZING")
                myStoreList = [
                    Store(name: "Walmart", address: "abcd", lat: 10, long: 20),
                    Store(name: "JCPenny", address: "kjfnv", lat: 23, long: 34)
                ]
                initialized = true
            }
                return myStoreList!
    }
    }
}


var a = Store.FACTORY_INITIALIZED_FLAG.getMyStoreList()

var b = Store.FACTORY_INITIALIZED_FLAG.getMyStoreList()

// only prints INITIALIZING once
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class var instance: SplitViewController {
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called *Type Property* in Swift.

> You define type properties with the static keyword. For computed type properties for class types, you can use the class keyword instead to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation. The example below shows the syntax for stored and computed type properties:

```
struct SomeStructure {
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
    static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
        return 1
    }
}
enum SomeEnumeration {
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
    static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
        return 6
    }
}
class SomeClass {
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
    static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
        return 27
    }
    class var overrideableComputedTypeProperty: Int {
        return 107
    }
}
```

Read more at link below,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254