# How to use singleton in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I already know the creation of `singleton` in objective-C, but how to make it in swift programming?
Dose it need some extra effort?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift