# Swift: Computed type properties in classes

Tags: properties, swift

I'm trying to understand something about type properties in swift.

The Swift Programming Language says

> For classes, you can define computed type properties only

So a computed property does not store a value itself, but it is calculated. That I understand. But I don't get how such a thing can apply to type properties. Such properties belong to the class itself and not to an instance of it.

So if you use a getter for such a computed type property, what could you possibly use to calculate it? It can't be any other type properties, as they too can only be computed properties. You would get a sort of loop of computed properties because there aren't any stored type properties.

In the same way, I also don't get what a setter would do. If you call the setter of a computed type property, what can it set? There are no stored type properties to be set.

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that stored class properties are only unsupported at the moment. The compiler error you get when you try to use them—"Class variables not *yet* supported"— suggests that they're on their way. Computed class properties don't necessarily *have* to make sense on their own.

However, computed properties don't always have to be based on the values of stored data. As it stands, you could use them for "static" read-only values associated with the class, say:

```
    class var ThisIsAClassConstant: String  { return "Woo" }
```

And people have already come up with ways to store associated values, for example, in the first two singleton patterns in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24147830/300836), the class property stores its state in either a global (but private) variable, or in a static variable inside a nested structure.

These are obviously a bit "workaroundy", but they're a way of achieving class-like storage while it's not officially implemented.