# Swift singleton tests

Tags: ios, swift, testing, tdd, quick-nimble

I am trying to learn testing with Quick and Nimble and I wrote simple singleton and some tests

Singleton:

```
public class LocationManager : NSObject {
// Singleton
public class var sharedInstance : LocationManager {
    struct Static {
        static var instance : LocationManager?
        static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
        }
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = LocationManager()
    }
    return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

My tests:

```
class LocationManagerSpec: QuickSpec {
override func spec() {
    describe("Location manager") {

        let locationManager = LocationManager.sharedInstance

        context("initialized") {
            it("is not nil") {
                expect(locationManager).notTo(beNil())
            }
            it("is unique") {
                let tempLocationManager = LocationManager()
                expect(locationManager).notTo(equal(tempLocationManager))
            }
            it("and shared instances are same") {
                let tempLocationManager = LocationManager.sharedInstance
                expect(locationManager).to(equal(tempLocationManager))
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can I test my singleton is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

To test that your Singleton is Thread safe I've made a little sample. You can find all code in this [Github repo](https://github.com/dfreniche/StackOverflowQA/tree/master/26296073) basically:

1. creating a bunch of threads asking for the singleton
2. storing every returned object inside an Array
3. checking all objects contained in that array are the same

I've found several problems (using Xcode 6.2 ergo Swift 1.1), even compiler crashes. So following [this accepted SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24147830/225503) I've changed your Singleton implementation avoiding the classic use of GCD. These pointers and unsafe mutable pointers you need to manage, and I was getting crashes because of that

So your Singleton class is now:

```
import Foundation


public class LocationManager: NSObject {

    public class var sharedInstance: LocationManager {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: LocationManager = LocationManager()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

}
```

And to test it, you need to wait until all Threads have finished. As the test runner runs on the MainThread you need to use a expectation

```
 describe("Accesing Location manager from multiple concurrent threads") {
            context("When created") {
                it("should return always the same object for every of these 500 threads") {
                    var allSingletons = Array<LocationManager>()

                    for i in 1...10 {
                        println("Launching thread \(i)")

                        dispatch_async(self.globalBackgroundQueue) {
                            allSingletons.append(LocationManager.sharedInstance)
                        }
                    }

                    expect(self.allSingletonsEqual(inArray: allSingletons, singleton: LocationManager.sharedInstance)).toEventually(beTrue(), timeout: 10)

                }
            }

        }
```

The important part is this one:

```
expect(self.allSingletonsEqual(inArray: allSingletons, singleton: LocationManager.sharedInstance)).toEventually(beTrue(), timeout: 10)
```

Here I'm just calling a function to be sure if every stored object is the same as the passed Singleton, and giving a 10 seconds timeout

The whole Test class:

```
import Quick
import Nimble
import QuickNimbleExample




class LocationManagerSpec: QuickSpec {
    var globalBackgroundQueue: dispatch_queue_t {
        return dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0)
    }

    func allSingletonsEqual(#inArray: Array<LocationManager>, singleton: LocationManager) -> Bool {

        for loc in inArray {
            if loc != singleton {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }


    override func spec() {

        describe("Accesing Location manager from multiple concurrent threads") {
            context("When created") {
                it("should return always the same object for every of these 500 threads") {
                    var allSingletons = Array<LocationManager>()

                    for i in 1...10 {
                        println("Launching thread \(i)")

                        dispatch_async(self.globalBackgroundQueue) {
                            allSingletons.append(LocationManager.sharedInstance)
                        }
                    }

                    expect(self.allSingletonsEqual(inArray: allSingletons, singleton: LocationManager.sharedInstance)).toEventually(beTrue(), timeout: 10)

                }
            }

        }


            }
}
```