# Scope of a variable inside a block, in a struct, in a func

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I want to do this:

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    struct Cell {
        static let height: CGFloat = {
            var cell:RentalViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RentalViewCell") as RentalViewCell
            return cell.bounds.size.height
        }()
    }
    return Cell.height
}
```

.. but the swift compiler throws a wobbly, and gives me a segmentation error in creating the SIL because of the tableView variable inside the block.

I know there are other ways I can write this, but can someone explain why it doesn't work this way and why I can't access tableView variable. I've tried using a capture list in the block to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to use `self` inside a block, so `self.tableView`

Comment: @Magnas That is correct if the variable is on the class, but tableView is also a parameter of the function. Either way, it doesn't work.

Comment: This feels like a bug.  I just tried it with a very simple function with the same architecture in a playground, and it crashed xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense to define a `struct` in a table view datasource / delegate method.

*Define* the struct elsewhere and - **if** you really have a good reason for it -
*use* it in the datasource method.

I suspect what you really want is to set the table view's `rowHeight` property.

Comment: The only reason for the struct is because I don't have static var's inside methods, like I would in Objective-C. I thought the reason would be clear from the code, but it's so I can find the cell height once. It does make sense here, because this is the only place it's used, so it's far nicer to keep it scoped to the function.

Comment: @mundi, this model is pretty much the standard for implementing a static variable in a function, typically for singletons.

Comment: Maybe, though it crashes, so I am not sure... In any case, I am not convinced about this use case. I take issue with doing this in a `datasource` method. `UITableView` has a `rowHeight` property for this particular purpose.

Comment: The compiler crash is caused by trying to reference a local variable from the enclosing scope, not by the basic model of putting a static in a locally defined structure.

Comment: @Mundi the reason for this pattern is because I want my cell, which is defined in a nib file, to be the ONLY place I define the row height. I don't want it declared twice - this is more of an anti-pattern than doing what I'm doing in a datasource method. If I alter my nib file design... my UI updates and I don't have to worry about setting the rowHeight too.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what your code is saying, you want a static instance, height, to be initialized over all invocations of `tableView(heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`  Does it really make sense then, for that static instance to be initialized with the value of a single call?  Imagine that this were a super class and that subclasses used different implementations of `dequeueReusable...`, which implementation should be used to determine the height for ALL subclasses?

A far better implementation would be to calculate it one time into an optional on the UITableViewController subclass and cache it there.

Comment: And, as @mundi points out, the correct way would actually be to calculate it one time and assign it to rowHeight and not override the method at all.

Comment: And why even define a struct if I only need the height??

Comment: That's the standard model for implementing a static variable in a function (typically as part of a singleton model implementation)  Since Swift doesn't allow static variables to be defined at the function level, you instead define a structure that contains a static variable.  The function initializer gives you the lazy, thread-safe initialization required for a singleton.  For more discussion see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)

Comment: It is all so illogical. Why have a static variable in a method for dynamic row heights? A simple constant is absolutely sufficient in this use case.

Comment: Well, I can see the desire to get it by pulling it out of the storyboard instead of a hard-coded constant that has to be coordinated between code and storyboard (or even two places on the storyboard, it's always annoyed me that I have to set the cell height two different places).  I agree that the method used here is overly complex for this specific problem.

Comment: Can I remind you that on my last line I stated 'I know there are other ways I can write this'... the point of the question was regarding the scope of a variable in the block, not on my pattern.

Comment: @Mundi TBH, I forgot about the rowHeight property on UITableView, which is why I was doing it in this datasource method. So I will change my implementation - but I'd still like to know about the scope of the variable in the block.

Comment: ..and if this were a superclass, and I overrode dequeueReusableCell to return a different cell, I'd likely override tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: too. (or set rowHeight to be a different height)