# Singleton in one line on Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

Please help me with Swift,
I need singleton with can inheritance.
I can do like this

```
class A {
    var defaultPort: Int
    required init() {
        self.defaultPort = 404
    }
    class var defaultClient: A {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: A? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = self.init()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

but in swift 2.0 we can do like this

```
static let defaultClient = A() //self.init()
```

but it creates an instance of the class A any way.
How i can use like this **self.init()**

```
static let defaultClient = self.init()
```

in order to be able to inherit

**UPD**
best way for now

```
class A {
    class func defaultClient() -> Self {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: A? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = self.init()
        }
        return instance(Static.instance, asType: self)
    }
}
```

here we need helper as

```
func instance<T>(instance: Any, asType type: T.Type) -> T {
    let reurnValue = instance as! T
    return reurnValue
}
```

because another way cast A to Self not exist, for now.

> p.s. crazy swift way! 
>   why i can not do **instance as! Self**

Comment: do the answers in these [very](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift/24147830#24147830) [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144915/swift-singleton-inheritance) help you out?

Comment: Unfortunately no,
but my post(code#1) answer that question

Comment: You've answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144915/swift-singleton-inheritance) with the same thing. So, is this a question or an answer? Is the answer only for Swift 1? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: its different question. here question in possible - Singleton Inheritance. my question in Singleton in **one line on Swift 2.0** with Inheritance.

Comment: Thanks. So, the answer you posted on the other page works, but you want it as one line in swift 2?

Comment: **self.init()** good work in **class var/class func**, but it is don't work in **static let** (compilation error)

Comment: yes i  want it as one line in swift 2

Comment: it was written in the subject header :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. You're looking for something like the class constant solution posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift/24147830#24147830), but which automatically uses "my own class" instead of explicitly creating an instance of a specific class... right?

That is, you want to turn this:

```
class Singleton  {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
}
```

into this:

```
class Singleton  {
    static let sharedInstance = SomeMagicThing()
}
class SingletonSubclass {}
```

where `SomeMagicThing` automatically creates a `Singleton` instance when you call `Singleton.sharedInstance`, and a `SingletonSubclass` instance when you call `SingletonSubclass.sharedInstance`. Correct?

#### Sorry, that can't be done (as of Swift 2.1).

Part of your issue is that `static` and `class` mean two different things. The `static` modifier means that the declaration it modifies is *associated only with a specific type declaration*. So, the `Singleton` type owns a pointer to a specific object -- its subclasses don't inherit that pointer. (And if they did, would it point to the same object or a subclass-specific one?)

If you could create a `class var` or `class let`, that'd (in theory) give you the kind of dispatch/inheritance you want. But trying that gives you an error (emphasis mine):

> class stored properties not **yet** supported in classes; did you mean `static`?

So it sounds like this sort of thing might show up someday.

Of course, the other side of the problem is finding a way to dynamically refer to the "current" type responsible for executing some statement. In the context of an instance method, you have `self.dynamicType` for such things... but there's no equivalent for classes. (`Self` is a type constraint, not an actual type.) This is a side effect of the type system in Swift being much more strict and static than that of Objective-C (for example, metatypes aren't just a special flavor of otherwise normal objects). [File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you'd like to see a change to that effect?