# Swift: Are addTarget actions only allowing class methods?

Tags: ios, swift, addtarget

I tried to add a target to a UIButton and stumbled upon a weird behaviour

if i try:

```
//h = a collection view header

switch myVar {

case "none":
    h.button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    func buttonTapped(sender:AnyObject) {

    sendFriendRequest(self.targetUser,nil
    } 

}
```

I get SIGABRT - with "selector not found"

but if I move the function out of the switch case and make it a method of my ViewController, everything works as expected.

Anyone has an explanation for that? Is is just not allowed or are there technical reasons?

Comment: you only need to make a method of your view controller. because the target is self! which means look for this method in the current class. otherwise specify the object that declares this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Selector`s don't need to be `class` functions, but they must visible to the object call the selector (i.e. can't be marked as `private` or inside a method).

Answer (score 0):

You can call **any method in the project** by using other `class's instance` instead of `self`.

Check this answer for the details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33068386/2125010