# Swift - create custom class of type `Array`

Tags: arrays, swift, singleton

How can I create a custom class in swift that is of type `Array`?
To be exact, I have a custom class of type `Car`, and now I want to create a singleton that is an array of `Car`s. (Because I want to be able to access it from anywhere in my app).

My workaround is to define my singleton as `NSMutableArray`. But I see that causes my some problems in my code. So I wish to define it as swift array.
How can I do it?

My code now is:

```
class MyCars: NSMutableArray {
    class var sharedInstance: MyCars {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: MyCars?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = MyCars()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swift array is implemented as struct, which does not support inheritance - so it's not possible

Comment: So what I did is the best way to do it? Is there another way to get the functionality that I want?

Comment: Why do you need inheritance? Wanting to add new methods or override existing ones?

Comment: No. I just want to have a singleton which is an `Array` of my `Car`s. But I think the `NSMutableArray` does not doing it perfectly..

Comment: @roi.holtzman what did you end up using? i am in the same mindset, in my case i have a custom class Visitor and i like array listVisitors. i also bump upon singleton, but not sure if this is the way to go.  In my case i like to add/delete visitors from the list.
Would you mind sharing your actual solution??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a singleton array of `Car` you don't need to create a new class - just a struct with a static member:

```
struct MyCars {
    static var sharedInstance = Array<Car>()
}
```

Note that the `sharedInstance` is initialized once - read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24073016/148357) for more info

**Addendum**

In case you want to use `MyCars` to refer to an array of `Car`, you can just define a typealias and use a different name for the struct containing the singleton, such as:

```
typealias MyCars = Array<Car>

struct Singleton {
    static var myCars = MyCars()
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `NSArray is not subtype of MyCars`. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: my code now is: `class MyCars {
    class var sharedInstance : MyCars {
        struct Singleton {
            static var instance = Array<Car>()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
}`

Comment: If you need the class for something else, than it looks good. If it's just a container for the static property only, then I think the struct is better - less code :)

Comment: But I have the struct there. I thought I should write it like this so I will have a singleton. You don't know why I the error I mentioned?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your 1st comment. How did you get that error? Remember that you have to access to the singleton as `MyCars.sharedInstance`

Comment: I think I got it :) I did't realise that you meant that I should use the code you wrote exactly. I thought I should've put it inside the singleton code. Anyway, now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Me too :) it was the code in your 2nd comment giving error. Btw glad you solved. I've updated my answer, so check it out

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, a singleton represents a class or structure for which there can be only one instance, ever. Even if someone tries to instantiate a new copy of the singleton they will wind up with a pointer back to the sole instance. (I got that idea from the Big Nerd Ranch Guide to iOS Programming, but it doesn't appear to be controversial). I don't think that the struct solution proposed above meets this criteria. For example, in a playground  create the the suggested struct (I've substituted 'String' type for 'Car' type to make testing easier):

```
struct MyCars {
    static var sharedInstance = Array<String>()
}
```

Then initialize the structure and show that the initialization "took":

```
MyCars.sharedInstance = ["Granada", "Pinto", "Chevette"]
println( MyCars.sharedInstance )
// prints all three car names
```

Now try to create a copy of the data and show it works, then modify the copy:

```
var myCars = MyCars.sharedInstance
println( myCars )
// the above prints all three cars
myCars.append("Gremlin")
```

Do the two variables point to different sets? Test:

```
println( MyCars.sharedInstance )
// the above prints three cars
println( myCars )
// the above prints four cars
```

So, in a Playground environment you do not get a singleton using a struct with a static var. This is unfortunate, as it would otherwise be a very simple way to implement a singleton array. I'm having big difficulties with this problem. A partial solution has been spelled out in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862978/creating-a-swift-singleton-data-model-that-is-subscripted-easy-and-assignable). In this solution you do get to reference the singleton using subscripts (so the singleton is somewhat array-like). But other array features (e.g. normal assignments) are missing.  That is, you can't use the following:

MySingletonClass.sharedInstance = [ "Granada", "Pinto", "Chevette" ]

Note: I'm pretty new to Swift; the above assertions don't carry much authority. There are changes going from Swift 1.1 to Swift 1.2 in how singletons are defined and those changes are summarized [here](https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton). The mechanism used by Swift 1.1 to define singletons is confusing, but Martin Rue has a very readable, step-by-step development spelled out [here](http://code.martinrue.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern-in-swift).

Good luck!
- George