# Creating a Swift singleton data model that is subscripted (easy) and assignable to an array (hard)

Tags: arrays, swift, singleton, assign

In testing, it would be convenient to have a simple singleton data model that acts like an array. That is, if I have a singleton class called MySingletonClass that supports a sharedInstance variable you should be able to change an element in the array with subscripts:

```
MySingletonClass.sharedInstance[ 0 ] = "New item 0"
```

Also, when the app opens, it would be great if a simple assignment allowed the system to provide initial values to the array:

```
MySingletonClass.sharedInstance = ["Item 0", "Item 1", "Item 2"]
```

I can do the first by providing the MySingletonClass with a subscript/get/set statement. However, I've not found any suggestions about how to perform the latter. Here's my class as it currently exists:

```
class MySingletonClass {
    class var sharedInstance: MySingletonClass {
        get {
            struct Singleton {
                static let instance = MySingletonClass()
            }
            return Singleton.instance
        }
    }

    var toDoItems = [ String ]()

    subscript( row: Int ) -> NSString? {
        get {
            if isValidIndex( row ) {
                return toDoItems[ row ]
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            assert(isValidIndex( row ), "invalid row number \(row) in a ToDo array of \(toDoItems.count) items")
            toDoItems[ row ] = newValue!
        }
    }
    /**
    Returns true if the passed index is valid in the toDoItems array

    The array is indexed from 0 to toDoItems.count - 1 (inclusive). The "row" value is judged
    to be valid only if it lies within this range.

    :param: row (Int), specifies an index number ( to count-1) in the toDoItems array
    :returns: a boolean to indicate if the passed index number is valid
    */
    func isValidIndex( row: Int ) -> Bool {
        if ( row >= 0 ) && ( row < toDoItems.count ) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

There is a kludgey way to assign initial values to this class using an array:

```
MySingletonClass.sharedInstance.toDoItems = ["zero", "one", "two"]
println( "first element: '\(MySingletonClass.sharedInstance[ 0 ]!)'" )
```

However, it forces the user to be aware of the "toDoItems" variable, which I would prefer to remain hidden. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To get the behavior that you're looking for you can create a private variable that's only accessible within the scope of your `MySingletonClass` file, but not actually part of the class itself.

```
private var instance: MySingletonClass!
class MySingletonClass {

    class var sharedInstance: MySingletonClass {
        get {
            return instance
        }

        set(newItems) {
            println("NewItems")
        }
    }

    private var toDoItems = [String]()

    subscript( row: Int ) -> String? {
        get {
            if isValidIndex( row ) {
                return toDoItems[ row ]
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            //assert(isValidIndex( row ), "invalid row number \(row) in a ToDo array of \(toDoItems.count) items")
            toDoItems[ row ] = newValue!
        }
    }

    private init(items: [String]) {
        self.toDoItems = items
    }

    class func initialize(items: [String]) {
        instance = MySingletonClass(items: items)
    }

    func isValidIndex( row: Int ) -> Bool {
        if ( row >= 0 ) && ( row < toDoItems.count ) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the class func `initialize` to create your shared instance without exposing `toDoItems` outside of the class.

```
class Controller {

    init() {
        MySingletonClass.initialize(["Get sack of crickets", "Pick up Lizards from daycare"])
        MySingletonClass.sharedInstance[ 0 ] = "Turn on Heat Lamps"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. It seems ungrateful, but is there a way to make the sharedInstance look like an array? Having subscripted it, it would be great if I could give it assignment, ".delete[]" or ".insert afterIndex:" features. -George

Comment: could you provide a few example statements so I can see exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: Blacksquare, thanks again for your reply. I think I may have been mistaken in thinking that this sort of class structure was necessary to make a singleton. At least, there is another discussion [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942237/swift-create-custom-class-of-type-array?rq=1) that asserts that a struct would do the job. I'm looking into it. Thanks for your kind replies! George

Comment: But to answer. I wanted to have statements like the following work: `MySingletonClass.sharedInstance.delete[ 0 ]` OR `MySingletonClass.sharedInstance.insert( "a new item", atIndex: 5 )`. (That is, give sharedInstance features of an array)

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that in Swift 1.1 you cannot use the standard assignment operator to assign an array to a singleton data model. In Apples book "The Swift Programming Language" there is a note saying:

> It is not possible to overload the default assignment operator (=).

Of course, you could make up your own assignment operator, but that would just leave your users guessing at your departure from normal array practice. You may see suggestions that a singleton array could be created using a "struct". I have not been able to make that suggestion work as a true singleton, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942237/swift-create-custom-class-of-type-array?rq=1).

The good news is that it is possible to set up a singleton data model that otherwise acts just like an array. That is, you can use the standard array functions like ".append", ".remove: atIndex:", etc. You only have to set up an empty Swift file and paste in the code below. The code is in two parts. The first is a protocol called Item. The second part is a class that establishes the singleton and encapsulates an array called "items". You can add, modify, or remove objects in "items" provided that the objects conform with the Item protocol. An example is shown below.

```
Model.data.append( myItemConformingInstance )
```

One word of warning, Xcode has some difficulties presenting singletons and this file makes Xcode really twitchy. You're welcome to modify it, but you will need patience!

```
import Foundation

/**
This module provides a simple Data Model for you to use in a Model-View-Controller setup. The class Model provides a singleton called data. You can treat the "data" singleton as if it were an array (see below for an exception related to assignments). Model.data stores objects that conform to the Item protocol. You provide your own class that conforms to this protocol, and also provides instance variablesimport Foundation
*/

protocol Item {

    /**
    Returns a single-line description of the data stored in an instance conforming to the Item protocol.

    Required to support plist-like description of the values stored in the items array

    :returns: (String) a description of the item's data
    */
    var description: String { get }

    /* Make your Item-conforming class also conform to Equatable. It should have a function that determines if two instances of your class are considered equal. The function must be in the same file, but NOT INSIDE your Item-conforming class. The function looks like:

       func​ ==(​left​: ​<NewItemClass>, ​right​: <NewItemClass>) -> ​Bool​

    */
}

// MARK: - start of Model singleton
/**
The Model.data singleton should look like a Swift Array, so it supports these functions:

ACCESSING ARRAY ELEMENTS

subscript(_: Int)

    gets or sets existing elements using square bracket subscripting. If the index is not valid for the current items array then an assertion is triggered. It is not possible to insert additional items into the array using subscripts larger than the current highest index for the items array (see .append).

subscript(_: Range<Int>)

    gets or sets a subrange of existing elements in the items array. If any of the indices in the specified range are not valid then an assertion is triggered. A subrange can be replaced (or eliminated) by a new array of objects conforming to the Item protocol, and the new array does not have to have the same number of entries as is specified by the Range.

ADDING OR REMOVING ELEMENTS

Model.data.append( newItem: Item )

    Adds a new Item-conforming object as the last element in the items array

Model.data.insertAtIndex( <Item>, atIndex: <Int> )

    Inserts an Item-conforming object into the items array at the given index. If the index is not valid then an assertion is triggered.

Model.data.removeAtIndex( <Int> )

    Removes the element in the items collection at the given index and returns the removed element. If the index is invalid then an asertion is triggered

Model.data.removeLast()

    Removes the last element in the items collection and returns the removed element. If the items array is already empty then an assertion is triggered.

Model.data.removeAll( keepCapacity: Bool)

    Removes all elements from the items array and by default clears the underlying storage buffer 

Model.data.reserveCapacity( minimumCapacity: Int )

QUERYING THE ARRAY OF ITEMS

Model.data.count

    Returns the number of elements in the items array.

Model.data.isEmpty

    Returns true if the items array is empty, otherwise returns false.

Model.data.capacity

    Returns an integer value representing the number of elements that the items array can store without reallocation.

Model.data.isValidIndex( index: Int ) (not standard)

    returns true if the given index is between 0 and items.count - 1, otherwise it returns false.

Model.data.description( optional limit: <Int>? ) (not standard)

    returns "empty" if the items array is empty, otherwise returns an enumerated list of Item descriptions. Ordinarily all items are listed, unless you provide a limit to tell the system how many items to list.

ISSUES

Although it would be nice to be able to assign Model.data usign the standard approach, e.g.

    *Model.data = [ item1, item2, item3 ]
    *THIS WON'T WORK, and the Swift 1.1 documentation says that the assign operator (=) cannot be overridden. Instead, use the underlying items array. E.G:
    *Model.data.items = [ Item1, Item2, Item3 ]

This approach uses the normal singleton method for Swift 1.1. Reportedly, it gets much simpler in Swift 1.2
*/
class Model {
    class var data: Model {
        get {
            struct Singleton {
                static let instance = Model()
            }
            return Singleton.instance
        }
    }

    var items = [ Item ]()

    // MARK: - ACCESSING ARRAY ELEMENTS

    subscript( index: Int ) ->  Item? {
        get {
            if isValidIndex( index ) {
                return items[ index ]
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            assert(isValidIndex( index ),
                "Fatal error: could not replace an item in Model.data using index number: \(index) in an items array of: \(items.count) items")
            items[ index ] = newValue!
        }
    }

    subscript( subRange: Range<Int> ) -> Slice<Item> {
        get {
            assert(isValidIndex( subRange.startIndex ),
                "Fatal error: could not retrieve a range of items in Model.data using low index number: \(subRange.startIndex) from an items array of: \(items.count) items")
            // in testing, it looks as though subRange is always set up to do a test of range
            // [ .startIndex..<.endIndex ], which means that .endIndex can be equal to the count
            // of elements in a array.
            assert(subRange.endIndex <= items.count,
                "Fatal error: could not retrieve a range of items in Model.data using high index number: \(subRange.endIndex) from an items array of: \(items.count) items")
            return self.items[ subRange ]
        }
        set {
            assert(isValidIndex( subRange.startIndex ),
                "Fatal error: could not replace a range of items in Model.data using low index number: \(subRange.startIndex) in an items array of: \(items.count) items")
            assert( subRange.endIndex <= items.count,
                "Fatal error: could not replace a range of items in Model.data using high index number: \(subRange.endIndex) in an items array of: \(items.count) items")

            items[ subRange ] = newValue
        }

    }

    // MARK: - ADDING OR REMOVING ELEMENTS

    /**
    Adds a new object conforming to Item at the end of items array

    :param: newItem (Item) an object conforming to the Item protocol
    */
    func append( newItem: Item ) {
        self.items.append( newItem )
    }

    /**
    Inserts a new item into the items array based on a passed index number

    The insertion places an object conforming with the Item protocol into the items array at the position specified by atIndex. Existing items that are at that position or higher are moved up by 1. Insertions fail if the passed index number is not valid.

    :param: newItem (Item) an object conforming with Item
    :param: atIndex (Int) the position in the list where the new task name is to be inserted.
    */
    func insert( newItem: Item, atIndex: Int ) {
        assert(isValidIndex( atIndex ),
            "Fatal error: could not insert a new item into Model.data with invalid index number: \(atIndex) in an items array of: \(items.count) items")
        self.items.insert( newItem, atIndex: atIndex )

    }

    /**
    removes an item at the items array at the specified index position

    If the specified index is not valid then a runtime error is generated. After a successful deletion, the items that started with index numbers higher than the passed index number will end with their index numbers decremented by 1.

    :param: atIndex (Int) the index number of the data item to be removed
    :returns: (Item)  This is the item that was removed from the items array.
    */
    func removeAtIndex(atIndex: Int) -> Item? {
        assert(isValidIndex( atIndex ),
            "Fatal error: could not remove an item from Model.data using index number: \(atIndex) in an items array of: \(items.count) items")
        return self.items.removeAtIndex( atIndex )
    }

    /**
    removes the last Item object in the items array in Model.data

    If the items array is empty then a runtime error is generated

    :returns: (Item) an object conforming to the Item protocol that was removed from the items array.
    */
    func removeLast() -> Item {
        assert( self.items.count > 0, "Fatal error: could not remove the 'last' item from Model.data since the items collection was already empty." )
        return self.items.removeLast()
    }

    /**
    Removes all items in the items array

    :param: keepCapacity: Bool if true then overrides default clearing of the underlying buffer
    */
    func removeAll( keepCapacity: Bool = false ) {
        self.items.removeAll(keepCapacity: keepCapacity)
    }

    /*
    Ensures that the underlying storage for the items array can hold the given total number of elements
    */
    func reserveCapacity(minimumCapacity: Int) {
        self.items.reserveCapacity( minimumCapacity )
    }

    // MARK: - QUERYING THE ARRAY OF ITEMS
    /**
    Returns an integer value indicating how many items the items array in Model.data can store

    You will have to reallocate the Model.data.items array if storage capacity is exceeded, using
    reserveCapacity.

    :returns: (Int) the number of items that the items array can store.
    */
    var capacity: Int {
        get {
            return self.items.capacity
        }
    }

    /**
    Returns the number of items in the items array
    */
    var count: Int {
        get {
            return items.count
        }
    }

    /**
    Returns true if the items array of Model.data is empty

    :returns: (Bool) true if the items array s empty, otherwise false.
    */
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        get {
            return self.items.isEmpty
        }
    }

    /**
    Returns true if the passed index is valid in the data array

    The items array is indexed from 0 to items.count - 1 (inclusive). The index is judged to be valid           only if it lies within this range.

    :param: index (Int), specifies an index number in for an object in the items array.
    :returns: a boolean to indicate if the passed index number is valid
    */
    func isValidIndex( index: Int ) -> Bool {
        if ( index >= 0 ) && ( index < items.count ) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    /**
    Returns a string in the form of an ennumerated list that shows a description for each item in the items array
    :param: limit: Int? tells the system to limit the list to "limit" items.
    :returns: (String) the ennumerated list of items
    */
    func description( limit: Int? = nil, title: String? = nil ) -> String {
        var msg = ""
        if let label = title {
            msg = "*** \(label)\n"
        }
        if items.count == 0 {
            msg += "the items array is empty\n"
        } else {
            var index = 0
            for nextItem in self.items {
                msg = msg + "[\(index)].\t\(nextItem.description)\n"
                index++
            }
        }
        return msg
    }
}
```

To test this, imagine you want the singleton array to represent items on a to-do list. Your class might look like:

```
import Foundation

    class ToDoItem: Item, Equatable {

        var name: String
        var createdAt: NSDate
        var done: Bool

        init( name: String, createdAt: NSDate, done: Bool = false ) {
            self.name = name
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.done = done
        }

        var description: String {
            get {
                return "Task Name:\( name ),  Created On:\( createdAt ),  Done: \(done)"
            }
        }


    }

    // External function to make equivalence between Items testable
    func ==( left: ToDoItem, right: ToDoItem ) -> Bool {
        return
                left.done == right.done
            &&
                left.createdAt == right.createdAt
            &&
                left.name == right.name

    }
```

The singleton array Model.data is in your project just by including its class. You can begin adding to the singleton array Model.data by instantiating your Item class and appending:

```
let task1 = ToDoItem(name: "task 1", createdAt: NSDate(), done: false )
let task2 = ToDoItem(name: "task 2", createdAt: NSDate(), done: false )
let task3 = ToDoItem(name: "task 3", createdAt: NSDate(), done: false )

Model.data.append( task1 )
Model.data.append( task2 )
Model.data.append( task3 )
```

In addition to the standard functions provided by Swift Array objects, there is a method, `description( limit:Int?, title:String: )`. The method returns a string listing each item in your singleton array. The limit parameter is optional, and tells the system that you only want to see a limited number of items from your array. The title parameter puts a text at the start of the description. For example:

```
Model.data.description( title: "First Items" )
```

This produces the following string:

```
> *** First Items: 
>[0].   Task Name:task 1,  Created On:2015-03-05 22:25:14,  Done: false
>[1].   Task Name:task 2,  Created On:2015-03-05 22:25:14,  Done: false
>[2].   Task Name:task 3,  Created On:2015-03-05 22:25:14,  Done: false
```