# Creating an NSDateFormatter in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am new to swift and am very unfamiliar with Objective-C. Could someone help me convert this to Swift? I got this code from Ray Wenderlich's best iOS practices - http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks

Where would you put this code? Would it go in a class file full of global variables?

```
- (NSDateFormatter *)formatter {
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        _formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"; // twitter date format
    });
    return formatter;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [dispatch\_once singleton model in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)

Comment: The duplicate shows how to implement a singleton model in swift, but the bottom line is that static variables are automatically lazily initialized using code protected by dispatch_once.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

1. If you're really looking for direct analog to the method in your question, you could do something like:

   ```
   class MyObject {

       // define static variable

       private static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
           let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
           return formatter
       }()

       // you could use it like so

       func someMethod(date: Date) -> String {
           return MyObject.formatter.string(from: date)
       }
   }
   ```

   The `static` properties, like globals, enjoy `dispatch_once` behavior for their default values. For more information, see the `dispatch_once` discussion at the end of the [Files and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7) entry in Apple's Swift blog.
2. Regarding best practices with date formatters, I would suggest:

   - Yes, it is prudent to not unnecessarily create and destroy formatters that you're likely to need again. In WWDC 2012 video, [iOS App Performance: Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=235), Apple explicitly encourages us to

     - Cache one formatter per date format;
     - Add observer for `NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification` through the `NotificationCenter`, and clearing/resetting cached formatters if this occurs; and
     - Note that resetting a format is as expensive as recreating, so avoid repeatedly changing a formatter's format string.

     Bottom line, reuse date formatters wherever possible if you're using the same date format repeatedly.
   - If using `DateFormatter` to parse date strings to be exchanged with a web service (or stored in a database), you should use `en_US_POSIX` locale to avoid problems with international users who might not be using Gregorian calendars. See [Apple Technical Q&A #1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html) or the “Working With Fixed Format Date Representations” discussion in the [`DateFormatter` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter). (Or in iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, use [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter).)

     But when using `dateFormat` with `DateFormatter`, use the current locale for creating strings to be presented to the end user, but use `en_US_POSIX` local when creating/parsing strings to be used internally within the app or to be exchanged with a web service.
   - If formatting date strings for the user interface, localize the strings by avoiding using string literals for `dateFormat` if possible. Use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` where you can. And if you must use custom `dateFormat`, use templates to localize your strings. For example, rather than hard-coding `E, MMM d`, in Swift 3 and later, you would use `dateFormat(fromTemplate:options:locale:)`:

     ```
     formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "EdMMM", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
     ```

     This will automatically show, for example, "Mon, Sep 5" for US users, but "Mon 5 Sep" for UK users.
   - The `DateFormatter` is now thread safe on iOS 7 and later and 64-bit apps running on macOS 10.9 and later.

For Swift 2 examples, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28511412/9).

Comment: Or better yet put `func someMethod(date: NSDate) -> String` in an NSDate extension.

Comment: In the first part, can't we just make it a private let? instead of the private static let? what is the reason for that

Comment: @ShabarinathPabba - First, I was answering the OPs question, in which they use `static`, so I was doing the same. Second, the idea is to minimize the number of date formatters you instantiate. So by making it a type property, it ensures that regardless of how many `MyObject` instances you have, you'll have only one formatter. But if you're in some class for which you know you'll only have one instance of `MyObject`, then, sure, use instance property rather than type property. Use your own good judgment that ensures that you don't unnecessarily instantiate many redundant date formatters.

Answer (score 21):

As [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) said, you must be careful with performance creating DateFormatters, use the tips from that WWDC session.

I am doing this as extensions of NSDate and NSDateFormatter (code tested in Swift 2, 3 and 4):

```
extension NSDate {
    func PR2DateFormatterUTC() -> String {
        return NSDateFormatter.PR2DateFormatterUTC.stringFromDate(self)
    }
    //... more formats
}

extension NSDateFormatter {
    fileprivate static let PR2DateFormatterUTC: NSDateFormatter = {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name:"UTC")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone
        return formatter
    }()
    //... more formats
}
```

Usage:

```
    let dateStringUTC  = NSDate().PR2DateFormatterUTC()
```

Comment: you can use `private static let` too

Comment: Changed, thanks for remembering

Comment: private is not working for me ... but thanks for the snippet and thanks @Rob too

Comment: The line `return NSDateFormatter.PR2DateFormatterUTC.stringFromDate(self)` complains of a `private protection level` issue

Comment: Change private to fileprivate to fix the 'private' error.

Comment: Updated with fileprivate

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to apply the Singleton approach found [here](http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/singletons-in-swift/).  This creates a singleton that could be loaded up with different the different formats you use within your application.  For example, you could access it anywhere in your application with `formatter.fromDateTime(myString)`

```
let formatter = FormatterFormats()

class FormatterFormats {
    var dateTime: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    class var sharedInstance:FormatterFormats {
        return formatter
    }

    func fromDateTime(dateString: String) -> NSDate {
        return dateTime.dateFromString(dateString)!
    }

    init() {
        dateTime.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    }

}
```

Comment: @rob Sorry, I don't follow. Would my code be better using static members? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: The singleton pattern is generally `final class FormatterFormats { static let shared = FormatterFormats() }`. It avoids polluting global namespace. You also should probably define `init` to be `private` to avoid accidentally instantiating other instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that and move the `NSDateFormatter` and the `onceToken` outside your function. Then you can do it like in your example:

```
var theFormatter:NSDateFormatter!
var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
func formatter() ->NSDateFormatter {
    dispatch_once(&token) {
        theFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        theFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
    }
    return theFormatter

}
```

But as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3203487/david) suggested, you should take a look at the d[ispatch_once singleton question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift).