# How to simulator static property in iOS 8.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

For a custom class, the following works fine.  But I'm getting errors that I think are specific to NSUserDefaults

```
class NSUserDefaultsManager:NSObject {
    struct Static {
        static var udefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    }  

    class var udefaults: [NSUserDefaults] {
        get { return Static. udefaults }
        set { Static. udefaults = newValue }
    }
}
```

On the `get` line, there is this error:

> 'NSUserDefaults' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

On the `set` line, I get this:

> 'NSArray' is not  subtype of 'NSUserDefaults'

The goal is to access udefaults like this `NSUserDefaults.udefaults`.  Do I need to create a property singleton for NSUserDefaults and access it like this NSUserDefaults.instance().udefaults?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be impossible. What you are trying to do is to create an *extension* of NSUserDefaults. The code to do this would look like this:

```
extension NSUserDefaults
{
    static let udefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
}
```

However, Xcode complains with the following error message:

> Extensions may not contain stored properties.

**UPDATE**

The following code compiles w/o any syntax errors, but it crashes Xcode :-)

```
extension NSUserDefaults
{
    class var shared : NSUserDefaults {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}


var qq = NSUserDefaults.shared
```

The error message is "Execution was interrupted, reason SIGABRT."

Comment: I don't want an extension.  Just a singleton but I don't think you can do it with NSUserDefaults for some reason.

Comment: If you want NSUserDefaults behave like a singleton then you have to add this behaviour , since it is not available in the original class. And when you add something to existing class, this is called extension.

Comment: Are you saying this is specific to NSUserDefaults or all classes (even custom ones)?

Comment: This is specific to standard library classes (UIKit, Foundation, etc.) . If you extend your own class, then it can contain additional properties. In the above example, replace "extension NSUserDefaults" with "extension MyClass" and it'll work (assuming you define MyClass somewhere)

Comment: I have a custom class and to create the singleton, I do not have to extend it.  I'm using the same code as shown above and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, for a custom class you can use static property. Btw., it is not even necessary to create a nested Struct as in your example, since Swift 1.2 supports "static let" in classes. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24147830/995049

Comment: Sorry for bugging you, but approach #2 from the link above actually compiles , but crashes at run-time :-) Seems like a bug in Xcode 6.2. So, here what I tried:

Comment: static properties are not allowed in iOS with Swift.  Can I add other methods into the extension?

Comment: Yes, functions can be added without problem. Just follow standard syntax inside extension: func myFunc() { ... }