# How can I share collection between view controllers without passing it back and forth?

Tags: swift, design-patterns

In my app I have 3 view controllers, each of them working on the same collection of elements. Is there a way to share that collection other than passing it back and forth while performing segues? Can I somehow make collection accessible by all 3? What would be the right way to go about it?

Comment: What about use core data?
Or maybe use a parent viewcontorller and treat the others as child?

Comment: Are there a lot of elements or only a few? In the last case, you could maybe use `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Well he had mention a collection, thats why I ignoer `UserDefailts` but yeah, could be another option

Comment: Make a super class for the view controllers with a static variable for the collection.

Comment: How about Sigleton ?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I think I will go with Singleton for now.

Comment: By the way, what's wrong with passing data from one view controller to the next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data between view controllers constantly without a segue? USING SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144857/pass-data-between-view-controllers-constantly-without-a-segue-using-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a singleton containing the collection of elements. Singletons however are often considered bad as they can cause more problems than they solve, so perhaps using Core Data would be a better option.

```
class Singleton {

    static let shared = Singleton()

    private init(){}

    private let internalQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.singletoninternal.queue",
                                              qos: .default,
                                              attributes: .concurrent)

    private var _elementCollection: Set<T>

    var elementCollection: String {
        get {
            return internalQueue.sync {
               _elementCollection
            }
        }
        set (newState) {
            internalQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._elementCollection = newState
            }
        }
    }

    func setup(collection: Set<T>) {
        _elementCollection = collection
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll look into Core Data and see if it's something I was looking for.

Comment: It will be a lot more hassle to set it up, and if all you're passing around is a simple set or array, the solution I provided will be suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton classes like below example

```
class YourClassName {
    static let shared = YourClassName()
    var test : String = "String"
    private init(){}
}
```

and then call your variables using

```
YourClassName.shared.test
```