# Best practice singleton in Swift

Tags: swift, singleton

I need an array that is accessible through out my app.  It will hold objects of Type ClassA.  I need to add/remove elements and access this array from multiple scenes.

What is the best or recommended method for building this singleton type class in Swift?

Or has Swift even come up with something for this yet?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24147830/148357) which also covers swift 1.2

Comment: He wrong with the first example in that post.  You can't use a static that way in Xcode 6.2 (note sure what version of Swift that is).

Comment: the direct link to the answer I posted above is for Swift 1.2 - if you are using earlier versions, look at the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24073016/148357)

Comment: I see now.  Xcode 6.3 is Swift 1.2.  Should I delete this question then since no answer will be provided.

Comment: The question is already marked as duplicate and linked to a question with relevant answers, so leaving doesn't hurt :)