# Global data accessible from all classes

Tags: arrays, swift, get, global

I've run into a problem. I want to have a few arrays that are accessible (get/set) from all other classes.

I tried working with a Singleton but I don't know how to set the data. How do you set that data and/or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have data accessible from all your classes you have two possibilities:

- Using a Singleton. Hated by some, useful to others. With this pattern you basically have a global access point to some data. Problems: kills multithreading (if writing at the same time to the Singleton) and also you have now been coupled to the Singleton's implementation. Good discussion on how to create a Singleton in Swift [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24024549/225503). Also lots of tutorials out there [on how to create a Singleton in Swift](http://code.martinrue.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern-in-swift)
- injecting your data (dependencies). You can use a Framework for that like [Typhoon](http://typhoonframework.org)

**Note**: also, you can write data to a file, use NSUserDefaults to pass data between classes, Core Data or other *horrible* design decisions. These two first are the most widely used for a reason