# Swift - Issue trying to access to Singleton object

Tags: swift, design-patterns, ios8, singleton

I am trying to implement the Singleton pattern on my app, without success so far. When I try to access my Singleton, it seems that the program is not accessing the real singleton, but a copy of it instead. Since this copy was not initialized, my app crashes, showing this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is an example of code I made:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static let sharedViewController = ViewController()

    var name: String = "Billy"
    var age: Int = 12

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("Old name from ViewController: \(name)")
        println("Old age from ViewController: \(age)")

        name = "Jack"
        age = 45

        println("New name from ViewController: \(name)")
        println("New age from ViewController: \(age)")

        println("singleton name from ViewController: \(ViewController.sharedViewController.name)")
        println("singleton name from ViewController: \(ViewController.sharedViewController.age)")
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is very simple. The class has two attributes initialized at creation, which are modified in `viewDidLoad()`. First, I try to access the attributes directly, and, then, through the Singleton.

Here is the output:

```
Old name from ViewController: Billy
Old age from ViewController: 12
New name from ViewController: Jack
New age from ViewController: 45
singleton name from ViewController: Billy
singleton name from ViewController: 12
```

As you can see, the data is still the same from the singleton point of view.  Unfortunately, the young Billy will never grow up.

I implemented all the three approaches of Singleton pattern in Swift, as it was said on this topic: [dispatch_once singleton model in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift), without any success.

I do not understand why I cannot access the real Singleton and only a copy of it (which is bad for a Singleton pattern).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, eventually, you won't be making a singleton of an `UIViewController`. What you probably want is to create a class, like `Person`.

*Still if you wan't to do it like you did **`static let sharedViewController = ViewController()` isn't the same object as `self`**.*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static let sharedViewController = ViewController()

    var name: String = "Billy"
    var age: Int = 12

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("VC - Name : \(name)")
        println("VC - Age : \(age)")

        println("Singleton - Name : \(name)")
        println("Singleton - Age : \(age)")

        ViewController.sharedViewController.name = "Jack"
        ViewController.sharedViewController.age = 45

        println("VC - Name : \(name)")
        println("VC - Age : \(age)")

        println("Singleton - Name : \(ViewController.sharedViewController.name)")
        println("Singleton - Age : \(ViewController.sharedViewController.age)")

    }
}
```

Console :

```
VC - Name : Billy
VC - Age : 12
Singleton - Name : Billy
Singleton - Age : 12
VC - Name : Billy
VC - Age : 12
Singleton - Name : Jack
Singleton - Age : 45
```

Anyway, try to document yourself a bit more on the Singleton pattern :-)

Comment: Ok I got it now ! 
If I want to use the Singleton pattern, even inside the class I have to modify the Singleton, and not `self`, if the particular data is going to be used outside the class.
Thank you for your help ;)