# Printing &self in swift, cannot assign to immutable value of type

Tags: swift

This is just an exercise in pointers in swift, but I was trying to write a function that would print the pointer to self, but I kept getting an error "cannot assign to immutable value of type C". Is this something that is even possible in Swift?

```
class C {
    static var c = C()
    var a = 1
    func printMyPointer() {
        printPointer(&self) //cannot assign to immutable value of type C
    }

    func printPointer(ptr:UnsafePointer<C>) {
        print(ptr)
    }
}

C.c.printMyPointer()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already explained in the other answer, you cannot pass a constant
as the argument for an in-out parameter. As a workaround, you can
pass an *array*, as this will actually pass the address of the first
element:

```
func printMyPointer() {
    printPointer([self])
}
```

But even simpler, use `unsafeAddressOf()`:

```
func printMyPointer() {
    print(unsafeAddressOf(self))
}
```

**Update for Swift 3:** As of Xcode 8 beta 6, `unsafeAddressOf`
does not exist anymore. You can convert `self` to a pointer:

```
    print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```

or

```
    print(unsafeBitCast(self, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self))
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually stumbled upon unsafeAddressOf a few seconds before this post, but I didn't know about the array workaround.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID173):

> You can only pass a variable as the argument for an in-out parameter. You cannot pass a constant or a literal value as the argument, because constants and literals cannot be modified. You place an ampersand (&) directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to an inout parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function.

Since `self` is immutable, you can't pass it as an `inout` parameter. Even though the method signature dosen't use `inout`, Swift treats pointer parameters like `inout`, according to the [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6):

> Swift allows pointer parameters to be treated like inout parameters, so you can pass a reference to a var as a pointer argument by using the same & syntax.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to get the address of a variable without indicating it as an inout parameter?