# Example of dispatch_once in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

Is there an example of how **dispatch_once** should be used in Swift? (Preferably one from Apple.)

Note: In this case, I'm [not using it for a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift); I want to run arbitrary code exactly once.

**Update:** I'm mainly interested in the convention recommended when using this in an instance method, but usage in a class method, function, and in the global context would be useful for completeness sake.

Comment: Here's one from GitHub: https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/7522f92bb5c4b667d506

Answer (score 28):

`dispatch_once_t` is type alias (`Int`). Header documentation:

```
/*!
 * @typedef dispatch_once_t
 *
 * @abstract
 * A predicate for use with dispatch_once(). It must be initialized to zero.
 * Note: static and global variables default to zero.
 */
typealias dispatch_once_t = Int
```

And here's the quote from `dispatch_once` documentation:

> The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static
>   scope. The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic
>   storage (including Objective-C instance variables) is undefined.

Token variable must be stored in global / static scope and must be initialized to zero, which leads to this code:

```
import Foundation

var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
dispatch_once(&token) { () -> Void in
  print("Called once")
}
```

It doesn't work if you omit `= 0` (`token` initialization), because compiler yields error *Address of variable 'token' taken before it is initialized* despite the fact that statics and globals default to zero. Tested in Xcode 7B2.

---

More examples based on comment. If you're inside `class` method you have several possibilities.

You can't declare static property inside method otherwise compiler yields *Static properties may only be declared on a type* error. This doesn't work:

```
class func doItOnce() {
  static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
  ...
}
```

Must be declared on a type. This was introduced in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 IIRC).

> “static” methods and properties are now allowed in classes (as an
>   alias for “class final”). You are now allowed to declare static stored
>   properties in classes, which have global storage and are lazily
>   initialized on first access (like global variables). Protocols now
>   declare type requirements as “static” requirements instead of
>   declaring them as “class” requirements. (17198298)

So, what we can do if we don't like globals?

**Static variable on a type**

```
class MyClass {
  private static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

  class func doItOnce() {
    dispatch_once(&token) {
      print("Do it once")
    }
  }
}
```

**Static in a method wrapped in struct**

Don't like static property on yur class? Would like to have it in your method? Wrap it in struct like this:

```
class func doItOnce() {
  struct Tokens { static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0 }
  dispatch_once(&Tokens.token) {
    print("Do it once")
  }
}
```

Actually I'm not aware of any Apple recommendation, best practice, ... how to do it for `dispatch_once`. Simply use whatever you like most, feels good to you and just meet criteria global / static scope.

Comment: Thanks for the info! One of the parts I was hoping to see was the convention Apple recommends for creating the token in a global/static scope when you are inside a class's method. I'm clarifying the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Senseful did add more examples. But I'm not aware of any Apple recommendation how to do it for `dispatch_once`. Just meet the criteria global / static and choose whatever feels good to you.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work with `override class func initialize()` of NSObject subclasses. The code inside the `dispatch_once` block is not executed.

Comment: The first section in this answer where `var token: dispatch_once_t = 0` is used to create the token is wrong, and will not ensure the dispatch block is executed only once.  The token should be created as a _type property_, like so: `struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }`.  Then, the dispatch call can be made:
        `dispatch_once(&Static.token) { () -> Void in
            print("Called once")
        }`

Comment: @sabajt from where did you get it's wrong? Docs still states that _The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope._ So, either static or global. This one is global. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, you are right @robertvojta: I was missing that the variable was stored in global scope, rather than a scope local to a method.  One thing that is a a bit misleading about the first example is that in most cases trying to call an expression in the global scope is now allowed, yielding the error _Expressions are not allowed at the top level_.  However declaring the variable in global scope, then calling `dispatch_once` inside a method will work fine.

Comment: Under Swift 4 you get the following error: `'dispatch_once_t' is unavailable in Swift: Use lazily initialized globals instead`

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who are curious, for me this approach has been useful for this purpose:

```
class SomeVC : UIViewController {
    private var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

    public override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        dispatch_once(&token) { () -> Void in
            self.doSomethingOnce()
        }

    }
}
```

By not declaring a static var it has the expected behaviour. That being said, this is definitely NOT RECOMMENDED for any serious project, since in the Docs (as your well said) it states:

> The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope. The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic storage (including Objective-C instance variables) is undefined.

If we don't want to run into any future weird bugs and undefined behaviour I would just stick to what Apple says. But  it's still nice to play around with these things, isn't it? =)

Comment: Just to clarify, by "expected behavior," you mean running exactly once *per instance* of SomeVC?

Comment: @Senseful yes, you are correct. At least that's the behavior I observed after testing it around the time I provided the answer

Answer (score -1):

the robertvojta's answer is probably the best. because i try always to avoid import Foundation and use 'pure' Swift solution (with Swift3.0 i could change my opinion), I would like to share with you my own, very simple approach. i hope, this code is self-explanatory

```
class C {
    private var i: Int?
    func foo()->Void {
        defer {
            i = 0
        }
        guard i == nil else { return }
        print("runs once")
    }
}

let c = C()
c.foo() // prints "runs once"
c.foo()
c.foo()

let c1 = C()
c1.foo() // prints "runs once"
c1.foo()

class D {
    static private var i: Int?
    func foo()->Void {
        defer {
            D.i = 0
        }
        guard D.i == nil else { return }
        print("runs once")
    }
}

let d = D()
d.foo() // prints "runs once"
d.foo()
let d2 = D()
d.foo()
```