# Cannot invoke 'dispatch_once' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I try to use dispatch_once, but I got this kind of error

[image: 'dispatch_once' error]

```
var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, { () -> Void in
        self.myCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.indexAtPosition(1), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left, animated: false)
    })
```

Comment: Please *copy/paste* your real code, not a screenshot.

Comment: Read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31256136/581190) to see how to use it.

Comment: @robertvojta : 

`var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
        dispatch_once(&onceToken),{
//            self.myCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.indexAtPosition(1), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left, animated: false)
        }`
it is error whenever I uncomment the commented line.

Comment: Interesting, I get this error message only if I remove `&` (Xcode 7 beta 4).

Comment: @DevAndArtist : It's always error to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't use `onceToken` in this way. As I wrote in my comment, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31256136/581190).

Swift compiler errors/warnings are misleading sometimes. They're improving them, but ... When this kind of error happens and I don't see a problem in my code, I'm going to add simple `return` at the end of my closure (to match closure type signature). Like this ...

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, { () -> Void in
  self.myCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.indexAtPosition(1),
  atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left, animated: false)
  return
})
```

... this makes compiler happier and now you see your real problem ...

```
Cannot invoke 'indexAtPosition' with an argument list of type '(Int)'
```

... and that's because you're calling method `indexAtPosition`, which is not class method, on `NSIndexPath` class. And you have to pass `NSIndexPath` object there.

If you would like to scroll to the first item, you have to call it in this way:

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
  self.myCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: false)
}
```