# How to create a singleton class in swift?

Tags: swift, singleton

I need to create a singleton class in Swift. Can anyone help me with the code? I already know that singleton classes are very helpful in creating generic code.

Comment: It's duplicate here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift

Answer (score 20):

There are many ways to create a Singleton Class in Swift. I am sharing with you one of the ways to implement this.

Write below code in Singleton Class.

```
import UIKit

final class GlobalData: NSObject {
   static let sharedInstance = GlobalData()

   private override init() { }

   func foo() { }
}
```

To access Singleton Class referencefrom other class:

```
let glblData = GlobalData.sharedInstance
```

OR access method directly

```
GlobalData.sharedInstance.foo()
```

Now we can use **glblData** as a reference to your singleton Class.

Comment: It is also a good idea to override the init and make it private, ie: `priviate init() { }` so that another instance cannot be created. (You don't want the singleton itself and multiple instances)

Comment: What if someone writes let data = GlobalData() somewhere else in code??
This will create another instance of the class, hence violating singleton, we should make its constructor private to follow singleton.

Answer (score 8):

```
class Singleton  {
   static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
}
```

Comment: Singleton class required private constructor (init). So it means you can't create more object of class "Singleton" by doing  let obj = Singleton(). you must need to private its constructor.

Comment: no its not singleton class, you can create an instance of Singleton class again. Singleton class means "Single instance of class throughout the whole application"

Answer (score 4):

You can create various Singleton. Below is the code for the simplest and most generic Singleton class:

```
class Singleton {
   static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
}
```

Comment: These are old methods prior to Swift 1.2 - @phnmnn is the easiest (and less error prone) way to define singletons

Comment: no its not singleton class, you can create an instance of Singleton class again. Singleton class means "Single instance of class throughout the whole application"