# Swift Memory Leak on NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I'm developing an app using the Singleton Pattern and Swift programming language. When I Profile the app with Instruments, I noticed that there's a memory leak pointing to an NSArray. Instruments is pointing to the following line of code (Please check screenshot). Can anyone find why the leak is happening? I tried to initialize the array Workout as:

```
workout = []
```

The leak wasn't reported. Maybe it has something to do with the unarchiving?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift in order for the correct singleton pattern in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer here: [Swift Decode Array Custom Class Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064086/swift-decode-array-custom-class-memory-leak)  It seems to be a bug. I had the same problem too. So instead of directly assign the value to `workout`, you can do:

```
if let wo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(Utilities.getFileURL("workout")) as? [ExceciseObject] {
    workout = wo.map { $0 }
}
```