# Swift Decode Array Custom Class Memory Leak

Tags: arrays, swift, memory-leaks, nscoding

I'm saving my app config using NSCoding and am getting a leak in Instruments when using DecodeWithKey.

Settings has a property stsSettings

```
stsSettings = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("stsSettings") as! StsSettings)
```

stsSettings has a property array of StsVariables

```
stsVariables = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("stsVariables") as! [StsVariable])
```

Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
StsVariable 1   0x7fe182d494f0  192 Bytes   Foundation  _decodeObjectBinary

Settings also has a property conversions which is an array of Conversion objects and this doesn't leak, so I can't work out what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced a memory leak in a similar situation. I resolved the issue by assigning the decoded array to a local variable and copy the elements to the property. However, I don't know why the memory leak was there in the first place.

```
let variables = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("stsVariables") as! [StsVariable])
stsVariables = [StsVariable]()
for variable in variables {
    stsVariables += [variable]
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I basically did the same thing but decoded to an NSArray and looped through that! Weird though!