# iAd doesn't show asynchronously once its delegate method is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iad

I have replicated the [iAdSuite with Storyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Introduction/Intro.html) in swift and the iAd works all fine across all view controllers, except that when the delegate method `bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)` is called the banner view does not appear instantly. I have to either rotate the simulator or go to another tab so that it appears.

I think this is the part of Apple sample code in Objective-C that I could not "translate" to swift? which may well be causing the iAd not show asynchronously once loaded...

```
+ (BannerViewManager *)sharedInstance
{
    static BannerViewManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[BannerViewManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

This is my `BannerViewManager` class with the `ADBannerViewDelegate` methods.

```
class BannerViewManager: NSObject, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - Shared instance
    static let sharedInstance = BannerViewManager()

    var bannerView: ADBannerView!
    var bannerViewControllers: NSMutableSet!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
        bannerViewControllers = NSMutableSet()
        bannerView.delegate = self
    }

    func addBannerViewController(controller: BannerViewController) {
        bannerViewControllers.addObject(controller)
    }

    func removeBannerViewController(controller: BannerViewController) {
        bannerViewControllers.removeObject(controller)
    }

    // MARK: - Ad banner view delegate methods

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        NSLog("bannerViewDidLoadAd")

        for bannerViewController in bannerViewControllers {
            (bannerViewController as! BannerViewController).updateLayout()
        }
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        NSLog("didFailToReceiveAdWithError %@", error);

        for bannerViewController in bannerViewControllers {
            (bannerViewController as! BannerViewController).updateLayout()
        }
    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(BannerViewActionWillBegin, object: self)
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(BannerViewActionDidFinish, object: self)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have managed to convert the objective-C code above to swift using [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift) but I still have the same problem. The iAd doesn't appear once its loaded. There's got to be some sort of change to the view so that it does, either rotating device or tapping another tab, etc...

So now my `sharedInstance` looks like this:

```
    static var sharedInstance: BannerViewManager {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: BannerViewManager? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = BannerViewManager()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have some iAd code in each view controller's `viewDidLoad`? If so, move the iAd code to each view controller's `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I've done this all the way like the sample code. So there is no iAd code in any view controller. Alternatively there is a `BannerViewController` in a container view and I've got this line `view.addSubview(BannerViewManager.sharedInstance.bannerView)` in its `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @DanielStorm - Checkout the sample code for `tabbedBanner` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Listings/TabbedBanner_TabbedBanner_BannerViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013458-TabbedBanner_TabbedBanner_BannerViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out what the problem is. It has nothing to do with the way I initialise the shared instance of the `BannerViewManager` class. In the matter of fact it turned out to give exactly the same behaviour whether using `dispatch_once` or the new swift 2.0 way.

The thing that caused the iAd not to show instantaneously when `bannerViewDidLoadAd` was invoked is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was actually never called!

I had to add some print statements here and there. Both in my code and Apple sample code to reach this conclusion.

So `setNeedsLayout` instead of `layoutIfNeeded` forced trigger the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

1. In general , attach the breakpoints in bannerViewDidLoadAd, and similar callback function.
2. Check you have the delegate  like in swift as class YourClassViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate.
3. Check your scenario , you said "I have to either rotate the simulator or go to another tab so that it appears" , so which method possibly could be responsible for it. I know you have guessed it.
4. READ Docs , Analyze.