# How to create Singleton in swift with arguments

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I learn the `Swift` Language and i need to create a **manager** like a Parse sdk.

For exemple when you initialize your Parse in app you write

```
Parse.setApplication("...", applicationId:"...")
```

And later you can write code like this

```
Parse.doSomething()
```

The method `doSomething()` use initial context.

Can you show me in my class should look like? I try some singleton exemple, but a have `MyClass.sharedAttribute.doSomething()` in case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dispatch\_once singleton model in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have shown is no indication of singletons whatsoever, it sounds and looks more like a ***static*** class with static members and properties:

```
class MyStatic {
    static var appIdA : String?

    class func setApplicationId(a : String) {
        appIdA = a
    }

    class func doSomething() {
        print(appIdA)
    }
}


MyStatic.setApplicationId("blabla")

MyStatic.doSomething() // prints Optional("blabla")
```

Of course there is the possibility that internally the class is a singleton, but `Parse` does not seem to be one, just looking at the functions it exposes.

The code comments even state

```
/*!
 The `Parse` class contains static functions that handle global configuration 
 for the Parse framework.
 */
```