# Singletons In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, singleton

The first time I learned how to Implement Singleton Pattern in Swift is in this Book `Pro Design Patterns in Swift`.

The way I started implementing the Singleton Pattern is in the example below:

```swift
class Singleton {

    class var sharedInstance: Singleton {
        struct Wrapper {
            static let singleton = Singleton()
        }
        return Wrapper.singleton
    }

    private init() {
    }

}
```

But then I found this implementation while reading about [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

```swift
class Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    private init() { 
    }

}
```

So my question is, what's the difference between the two implementations ?

Comment: You'll find it all in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift. To make it short: The second implementation is the currently recommended one. The first implementation stems from Swift <= 1.1, where static class properties were not yet supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in *Swift 1* days, `static let` wasn't implemented yet. The workaround was to create a wrapper `struct`. With *Swift 2*, this is not needed anymore.