# "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" with Realm and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Last Friday, it worked. Today, it doesn't work anymore.

I have a colleague for whom it's working fine.

I have reinstalled my pods, cleaned the project, tried different targets. I have no error messages.

Here is the faulty code:
[image: Faulty code]

This is confusing to me. Any idea what I should be looking for ?

Comment: Obviously `Realm()` throws an error, but since you're using `try!` instead of using Do-Catch and error handling, you're left with just a crash instead of an error message.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the simulator?

Comment: @EricD Thanks for noticing. But how can I declare an app wise variable with a do/catch statement as it is not allowed at the top level?

Comment: @bcamur Thanks though it didn't change anything.

Comment: Is any information logged to the console? You can look by selecting View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console within Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: I don't work with Realm, so I could be off-topic here... Don't hesitate to tell me.*

We see that `Realm()` throws an error, but since you're using `try!` instead of using Do-Catch and error handling, you're left with just a crash instead of an error message.

Since you're asking in a comment "But how can I declare an app wise variable with a do/catch statement as it is not allowed at the top level?", I would just make the property an Optional and populate its content when the view/window/init loads.

At the root of the class:

```
let realm: Realm?
```

In `viewDidLoad`, or `init`, or any other method called at startup that will fit your needs:

```
do {
    self.realm = try Realm()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
    // handle errors here
}
```

Then in your app, safely unwrap before usage:

```
if let realm = self.realm {
    // do your work with `realm`
}
```

or even better, follow the "happy path" and use guard:

```
guard let realm = self.realm else { return }
// do your work with `realm`
```

If you don't want to have to handle unwrapping the Optional property everywhere, you can declare it as an *implicitly unwrapped optional* instead:

```
let realm: Realm!
```

But then in the init part you must not forget to stop the app execution if it's nil, before trying to access the value.

```
do {
    self.realm = try Realm()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
    fatalError("Can't continue further, no Realm available")
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to have a generic constant/variable I can access from anywhere? So far, I used to declare a variable before `AppDelegate` and access it from anywhere. Like so: https://gist.github.com/AdrienGiboire/ab874b1faead0089a38ca608f5f0ee63 which is not possible in what you propose me to do. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, your way of doing it is considered a bad pattern because global variables like this is can cause problems. If you really - and I mean *really* - need to work with something global, at least embed it in a singleton like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36012158/2227743 Then you can access the singleton's sharedInstance from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. That's precious advice. I'm new to iOS development :) So you suggest I declare the variables every time I need them even if it's everywhere?

Comment: No, the key is "dependency injection". When you need to use `realm` outside of the class you created it in, you *send it* to the object that needs it. Like, you init another class with a `realm: Realm` parameter and you pass the existing instance. Or you just pass the realm instance to a method, etc. // You *can* be global, with a singleton, but it's not ideal at all. It's attractive because easy but is a pain to test, and is dangerous if the app uses multiple threads (like: what happens if two threads modify the value of a property in the singleton *at the same time*...).

Comment: "Dependency injection" is just the safe way of doing this. :) Good explanations [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/singletons/) (for Objective-C but the reasoning still applies) and excellent blog article [here](http://bartjacobs.com/dependency-injection-in-swift/) specifically about Swift.