# IOS- Reusable Singleton class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, singleton

I have an singleton class with set of properties where I will store some global values that can be used across project.

In a place I am in a need of class with same property as singleton class. So my question is is this a right way I can use my same singleton class as private.?

```
let medicine1 = Medicine.sharedInstance()
medicine1.frequency = 2
print("medicine1 \(medicine1)")
print("medicine1.frequency: \(medicine1.frequency)")

        let medicine2 = Medicine()
        medicine2.frequency = 4
        print("medicine2 \(medicine2)")
        print("medicine2.frequency: \(medicine2.frequency)")
        print("medicine1.frequency: \(medicine1.frequency)")
```

Comment: It looks like `Medicine` shouldn't be a singleton.

Comment: Unfortunately, the term "singleton" is often used for what is in fact a "shared instance".

Comment: It should be workable, though, like others, I wouldn't call it a singleton.  Consider NSNotificationCenter from the SDK.  The docs say, "You typically don’t create your own"...but there's no singleton guarantee, just a usual default.

Comment: Anyway separate instance of singleton will never affect the actual singleton values right ?

Comment: @nik With a true singleton, there's no such thing as "separate instance of singleton", that's the whole point: having one single, *unique* instance shared for all the code. If it's not a unique shared instance it is not a singleton, it is just a shared object.

Comment: @EricAya My point here is not creating a separate instance of singleton class. My question here was Is it I can reuse the singleton class(i.e class and its properties) to store another object's value

Comment: Check my code above sharedInstance() will return same object gain and again which nothing but singleton. And Medicine() is an another object of medicine class. Am i doing right is what my question here

Comment: If you're able to make a new instance of `Medicine` then `Medecine` is not a singleton. Only the `sharedInstance` should be available. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36012158/2227743 -- If you need/want this other instance, then you should *not* make `Medecine` a singleton. It's one way or the other, not both.

Comment: You should also read this recent one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38819314/2227743

Comment: @EricAya Thanks for clarification