# Init method in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

```
class MissionControl {

    var nameField=""
    var surnameField=""
    var phoneField=""
    var tcIdField=""
    var photoField=""


    class var sharedInstance: MissionControl {
        struct Singleton { static let instance = MissionControl() }
        return Singleton.instance
    }



    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

}
```

I was using this class with Swift 2.3 and it was working well. But I couldn't use with Swift 3. I am getting following compiler errors:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its
>   superclass
>
> 'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class

How can I fix them?

Comment: This is an obsolete way of making a "singleton". Please follow the preferred way like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36012158/2227743

Comment: Regarding your issue: your class does not inherit from anything, so why would you call super? It's not needed.

Comment: Do you want to make it a singleton class? if yes, "init" should be private, also, there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix this by not calling `super.init()`. Your class is not declared as inheriting from another base class so there is no `super.init()` to call.

By the way, for your shared instance I would just do

```
static let sharedInstance = MissionControl()
```

Comment: Ok, I changed my code to this: http://prntscr.com/dac7sw  and accessed from another view controller with http://prntscr.com/dac851 But i couldn't see my print on log section. Where is the problem?

Comment: @TolgayToklar Not sure what the issue is but I think it happens lazily i.e. not until the shared instance is needed and if you don't use the shared instance, it may be that the `let` statement is being optimised out. Try not only doing an assign but also calling a method on sharedInstance.