# Design Pattern for Realm Database Swift 3.1 - Singleton

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, realm

> I'm working on [RealmSwift](https://realm.io/), which is a modern database replacement of CoreData/SQLite in Swift.

I'm wondering how to implement a design for a `Class` which can manage/handle all the queries for [RealmSwift Framework](https://realm.io/)

This question is somewhat similar to implementing SQLite Model Manager but for RealmSwift.

Specifically I don't require a singleton object/instance mention above.

Comment: The TL;DR duplicate for this is [Using a dispatch\_once singleton model in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)  The bottom line is what TiM said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realm has a rather clever internal caching system where previous instances of `Realm` are held onto and recycled each time a call like `let realm = try! Realm()` occurs. As such, it's not really necessary, nor recommended to try and incorporate a `Realm` instance itself into a singleton.

If you want to heavily customise your `Realm` instance's settings, you'll normally do that through a Realm `Configuration` object, which is static and thread-safe. If that's the case, it would be more appropriate to have a singleton (or even just a static class method) that returns the appropriate `Configuration` object when you need to create a new `Realm` instance.

[that thing in swift](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/) has a page on how to create singletons in Swift, and it's essentially just a single static property of a class implementation:

```
class SomeManager {
    static let sharedInstance = SomeManager()
}
```

Comment: Also private init() is recommended to restrict multiple instantiations of your SomeManager class. Otherwise your class is not a real singleton.

Comment: @TiM i require an implementation idea for a manage class which will be used for handling all the queries related to Realm

Comment: I have created a RealmManager class (DB manager) that has all calls dealing with realm. For example, getUserInfo, saveUserInfo. I don't allow realm to touch anything outside of this class and I use class func where I instantiate realm for each function instead of a shared realm singleton instance for the entire manager. I have run into a crazy issue where an object can be tied to a previous realm instance if I chain these functions (object is open in another realm instance). Since you can't close realm manually, would this be ok to turn it into a singleton at this point instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use an enum with one case:

```
enum Singleton: Protocols {
    case instance
    /// methods
}
```

Used like:

```
Singleton.instance.method(args)
```