# Reuse UIViewController instance across theards

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization, thread-safety

This is our scenario,we have VC A,B and C. As well, we have VC X.

I need to use & present VC X within A,B and C.

I don't want to re-create an instance every time i'm on each VC.
So basically i was thinking on creating global instance/property at the `App Delegate` and initialize it there,and just present VC X when needed.

```
 vcX = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IAP") as! newIAPClass
```

Does this could cause unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts on reusing a single copy of a viewController X:

1. Thread safety should have nothing to do with it as **all user interface interactions need to be performed on the main thread**.
2. Each instance of a viewController can only have **at most one parent** at a time.  So as long as you only use X once in your view hierarchy, you should be OK.  For example A presents B which presents X, and then X returns to B which returns to A.  Then A presents C which presents X.  This would work fine since X only has one parent at any given time.
3. Doing this would mean that X would retain all of its settings between presentations, so it would be the responsibility of the presenter to *clean it up* and  properly initialize it before presentation.  By keeping a permanent global copy of X around, it will retain all of the data it has between calls.  For example, if there is an input text field, that text field will still contain the text from a previous use.  The presenter will be responsible for reinitializing any data that viewController X retains and uses.  This would include a delegate pointer.

---

An example of a scenario that would cause problems:  A, B, and C are all contained in a `UITabBarController`.  Each one can present `X` so that the user can change settings.  This will fail if A presents X and then the user switches tabs to B and then presents X again because now X will have both A and B as parents, which can't work.

---

Instead of creating viewController `NewIAPClass` as a global, consider making it a *Singleton*.  See this answer: [Creating a Singleton in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24024549/1630618)

So you'd create `NewIAPClass` like this:

```
class NewIAPClass: UIViewController {
    static let sharedInstance = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IAP") as! NewIAPClass

    // All of the other stuff that makes up NewIAPClass ...
}
```

Then every time you want to use `NewIAPClass`, you'd refer to it as `NewIAPClass.sharedInstance`.

Comment: Hey vaca! Thank you for responding. I would like to understand closure number 3.What does "Clean it up" means? assiging nil to the delegation. etc?

Comment: As I expected, awesome,thank you! So as long I'm dismissing X, it's should be fine, right? :) btw, does using global property, is fine? (Assuming we are doing as we said)

Comment: I actually did tried use of singleton, i know it's the standard, but I couldn't really understand it lol. I will try to find good example of it. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing! I just started looking for it, awesome! Thank you! Mind if i ask a question about singleton? Or i should open a new question? I just don't mean to get off subject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110004/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-vacawama).

Comment: Hey @vaca. For the last two days i'm trying to figure this SharedIntance problem. Would you mind take a look? I honestly can't understand what's going on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852386/loading-uiviewcontroller-from-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-nil-outl