# Ios swift class without instantiate

Tags: ios, swift, class

How do you (if possible) create a class that anything that references it gets the same object?

So, if I had a LoginClass

and I dont want to create a new instance in each file but rather be able to just do

LoginClass.userID

in any file without first creating an instance of it?

Answer (score 1):

It possible. Use **singleton**:

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)

[Tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

### You are looking for a Singleton

This is the code

```
class Login {
    static let sharedInstance = Login()
    var userID: String?
    private init() {}
}
```

### This is how you retrieve the same instance

```
Login.sharedInstance
```

### And this is how you use it

```
Login.sharedInstance.userID = "123"
```

In a different point of your code...

```
 print(Login.sharedInstance.userID) // 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating one instance per application life cycle means you want to implement Singleton pattern. You can implement singleton like this

```
class LoginManager {
    static let sharedInstance = LoginManager()

    var userId:String?
    var name:String?

}
```

And now you can use this like

```
LoginManager.sharedInstance.userId
```