# Declaration of singleton as a computed property memory allocation mechanism

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

Here I was going through different ways of creating a singleton class. All along I found this git repo -https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton

I found the following code sniper for creating singletons.

```
class SingletonB {

    class var sharedInstance: SingletonB {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: SingletonB = SingletonB()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

}
```

Okay the class property `sharedInstance` is a computed property. Computed property are not allocated any memory & the value of the property gets computed each and every time it gets called.

**Question -** If so is the case then it violates the principle of singletons that there shall be only 1 instance of the class through out the whole application and the instance is initialised only once. But here in case of computed property the value for `sharedInstance` gets computed each and every time we call this property.

**So how is this mechanism going behind the screens ?**

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift, which 1) shows a simpler method, and 2) explains how it works (the `static let instance` property is assigned only once).

Comment: But anyways the code gets running all the time we call the property. Isn't it ?
So does that hamper?

Comment: Yes, but `return Static.instance` returns the *same instance* on each call. That mechanism was necessary in early versions of Swift, where static *class* properties were not supported. But you should find all that in the referenced Q&A.

Comment: Okay then then as per my question, the computed property does not get allocated in the memory but the static property gets allocated in the memory once and for all.