# Call the same view controller from many other view controller programmatically without using any segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController")
```

Run code above in multiple view controller they will init multiple `someViewController`. How to call the same `someViewController` instance in this case?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's just that you may think doing in the good way, but there could be an alternative. So why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm developing a music app which has to call a PlayerViewController from multiple OtherViewController (example: https://github.com/jaredchu/MusicPlayerTransition). Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: A sharedInstance could be interesting. If you want to show it always (available in each ViewController), you may be interested on how does SWRevealViewController or others stuff like it, keeps their panel always visible, etc.

Comment: I will go research for SharedInstance. Thanks for your time and your answer.

Comment: Check my answer . and tell me its helpful for you or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need to use for that effect  [Using a dispatch_once singleton model in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)
More specific: 
Swift :

```
 class SomeViewController {
      class var sharedInstance: SomeViewController {
        struct Static {
          static let instance: SomeViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController")
        }
        return Static.instance
      }
    }
```

Objective C:

```
    + (instancetype)sharedInstance; // add this to SomeViewController.h file
    + (instancetype)sharedInstance { // and this in SomeViewController.m
       static SomeViewController *instance = nil;

       if (!instance) {
          UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
          instance = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeViewController"];
       }

       return instance;
    }
```

then use with [SomeViewController sharedInstance]

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for Objective-C answer, I will try to convert your code in to Objective-C.

Comment: I have updated my answer. When you first asked, the code was in swift, so I assumed that was what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
someViewController *afv=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someViewController"];
afv.getdata();
[self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:afv animated:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let someobject: someViewController = (mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! someViewController)
someobject.getdata()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(someobject, animated: true)
```