# How to allocate static object defined in a Swift class inside an objective-C class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, forward-declaration, language-interoperability

How do I access to the shared instance of "SharedManager" declared in my Swift file from my Objective-C class?

**Steps:**

I have declared an object in a Swift file as following:

**Swift Class Declaration:**

From this [instructions][1] I did:

```
// Swift class
class SharedManager{
    static let sharedInstance = SharedManager()
}
```

**From Objective-C class:**

In AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"

@class SharedManager;
@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// How do I access to the shared instance of "SharedManager" ?

}    

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a Swift class in Objective C, it must inherit from an Objective C class (such as NSObject), or be marked with `@objc`.

Either:

```
@objc class SharedManager {
    static let sharedInstance = SharedManager()
}
```

Or:

```
class SharedManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = SharedManager()
}
```

Then you can use it just like any other Objective C class:

```
SharedManager *manager = SharedManager.sharedInstance;
```

Comment: What does that mean? What's the issue?

Comment: It says property sharedinstance not found

Comment: I think you have to make `sharedInstance` `public`

Comment: @mm24: SharedManager must inherit from NSObject in order to be used in Objective-C.

Comment: @mm24 oh yeah, it must either inherit from an Objective C class, or be annotated with `@objc`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late to the party, but you should also prepend the **@objc** marker also for the shared instance:

```
@objc
class VoiceShortcutsManager: NSObject {
    @objc static let shared = VoiceShortcutsManager()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        updateVoiceShortcuts(nil)
    }

...

}
```

This way you can safely access the shared instance in objective-c:

```
...

[VoiceShortcutsManager shared];

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` in the Objective-C implementation file (`.m`) where you want to refer to the Swift type.
2. Subclass your `SharedManager` from `NSObject`:

```
class SharedManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = SharedManager()
}
```

This will work at least with Swift 2.3 and 3 (i.e. Xcode 8 & current macOS / iOS SDK versions, with or without "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" on in build configuration). I fail to remember if prior to Swift 2.3 you can make the above work with additionally marking the class with the `@objc` attribute or whether static variables declared in Swift are entirely unavailable to Objective-C code?

Answer (score -1):

```
 class MyClass { 
    private static let _sharedInstance = MyClass() 

    class func sharedInstance() -> MyClass { return _sharedInstance } 
}
```

Retrieve the singleton via

```
MyClass.sharedInstance()
```

Comment: The bridging header file is for exposing Objective C to Swift, the opposite of what OP needs. OP needs to use the auto-generated header file created by Xcode, which they already have imported (`#import ProjectName-Swift.h`).

Comment: I have the bridge header to export Swift classes as Alexander said

Comment: class MyClass {

    private static let _sharedInstance = MyClass()

    class func sharedInstance() -> MyClass {
        return _sharedInstance
    }
}

Retrieve the singleton via MyClass.sharedInstance()

Comment: Hi Bassam, adding the method worked. Would you be able to edit your answer reflecting this and then I'll accept it?