# How to create several cached UIColor

Tags: swift, uicolor, swift-extensions

I have custom colors within my code. I use them several times and I would like to have them allocated only once.

## The situation / problem

If we get a look at UIColor headers we can see the following :

```
[...]

// Some convenience methods to create colors.  These colors will be as calibrated as possible.
// These colors are cached.
  
open class var black: UIColor { get } // 0.0 white

open class var darkGray: UIColor { get } // 0.333 white

[...]
```

I've created an `extension` of UIColor, like so :

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    
    class func colorWithHexString(_ hex: String) -> UIColor {
        
        print("\(#function): \(hex)")
        
        // some code, then it return a UIColor

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )

    }
    
    // Option A
    open class var myColorOne : UIColor {
        get {
            return colorWithHexString("AABBCC")
        }
    }
    
    // Option B
    class func myColorTwo() -> UIColor {
        return colorWithHexString("DDEEFF")
    }
}
```

From there I can use my colors easily, with either having a variable or a function.

```
// A
UIColor.myColorOne

// B
UIColor.myColorTwo()
```

Sadly, I'm not fully happy with that. Indeed, every time I want to use those colors : a new UIColor allocation is made.

## What I've tried

Apple managed to make their color cached apparently. I would like to do so myself too. I've tried several things but none seems to be ideal.

### 1 - Using dispatch_once ✗

As visible on Swift page : *the free function `dispatch_once` is no longer available in Swift.*

### 2 - Creating a constant (let) ✗

I get the following error : *extensions may not contain stored properties*

### 3 - Creating a singleton ~

It does work (each color are created only once) with the following

```
import UIKit

class Colors : UIColor {
    
    // Singleton
    static let sharedInstance = Colors()
    
    let myColorOne : UIColor = {
        return UIColor.colorWithHexString("AABBCC")
    }()
    
    let myColorTwo : UIColor = {
        return UIColor.colorWithHexString("DDEEFF")
    }()
    
}
```

But it forces me to have one more file and call my colors like so

```
Colors.sharedInstance.myColorOne
```

Isn't there any way to get the colors I want like that `UIColor.myColorOne` and have them cached like Apple does ?

Comment: @Grimxn, aren't global variable (even lazily initialized) a *bad practice/idea* ? Also, it won't be call like other colors `UIColor.white`. How did Apple wrote theirs... Might need to store the color after first initialization and fetch it on later calls (not sure about performance here, versus the singleton).

Comment: ...</troll> ... sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in 
[Using a dispatch_once singleton model in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift/24147830#24147830), i.e. static 
constant stored properties
which are initialized lazily (and only once). These can be defined
directly in the `UIColor` extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: String) {
        // ...          
    }

    static let myColorOne = UIColor(hex:"AABBCC")
    static let myColorTwo = UIColor(hex:"DDEEFF")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way to do it, but using a global variable (like Grimxn mentioned in the comment) is one way to solve the problem.

Below is an example you can copy & paste into a playground:

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    class func colorWithHexString(_ hex: String) -> UIColor {
        print("allocate color")
        // do you conversion here...
        return UIColor.black
    }

}

private let myPrivateColorOne = UIColor.colorWithHexString("#ffffff")

extension UIColor {

    open class var myColorOne: UIColor {
        get {
            print("get color")
            return myPrivateColorOne
        }
    }

}

UIColor.myColorOne
UIColor.myColorOne
```

When you execute the code, the getter will be called twice, but `colorWithHexString` only once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your singleton to store the generated UIColor values as above and solve the Colors.sharedInstance.myColorOne naming problem by extending UIColor and putting the access in there:

```
extension UIColor {
    class func myColorTwo() -> UIColor {
        return Colors.sharedInstance.myColorTwo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3:

```
extension UIColor {
    class func color(hexString: String) -> UIColor {
        // ...
    }

    static let myColorOne = color(hexString: "AABBCC")
}
```