# Swift singleton that does not look like a singleton

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

In Objective-C one can make a singleton that does not have a *sharedInstance* or similar class call simply by making the `-init` method reference the status singleton variable, like so

```
static MyObject *sharedObject;

/*
 * The init will return the actual singleton instance if called directly. 
 * The first time called it will create it and intialize it.
 */
- (instancetype)init
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        id myself = [super init];
        if (nil != myself) {
            [self initialize];
            sharedObject = myself;
        }
    });

    return sharedObject;
}
```

So a user could call this `MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];` as many times as he wanted and would get the same object back each time.  But it is not obviously, from syntax, a singleton.

I am trying to get a similar functionality in Swift, where I can return the same object each time (an NSObject subclass) but so that it is not obviously a singleton.

I would call it `var myObject = MyObject()` or when bridging to Objective-C as above but they would all reference the same object.

I am familiar with the normal *sharedInstance* method of singleton in Swift.

Suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

This is not the same as the dispatch_once in Swift answers as that still uses a *sharedInstance*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a dispatch\_once singleton model in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/using-a-dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift)

Comment: This isn't possible in Swift since an initialiser implicitly returns  `self` (or `nil` if a failable initialiser fails)

Comment: Even though this was/is possible in Objective-C, you **shouldn't**. Init has a very well understood, common meaning. Changing it to instead implement singleton functionality is an unexpected diversion from the norm.

Comment: @Alexander  I would disagree to a certain extent.  There are lots of cases where you can return other than the original self.   All that is expected of alloc/init is that you get a nil or an object of the correct type back.  (My needs now are mostly academic in terms of trying to figure it out vs actually having a case where it should be this versus the standard singleton pattern)

Comment: It doesn't matter if a singleton looks like a singleton or not: If your code depends on them, it isn't good code.

Comment: @vikingosegundo It's not about depending on it having the characteristics of a singleton. The issue is that it's unnecessarily changing the semantics of initialization. For one, this causes an unnecessary allocation (calling `alloc`, only to have the `init` immediately discard its memory).

Comment: @chadbag Yeah, such cases are class clusters, but you're still generally assigning the meaning of "create a new thing of this (sub)type" to initialization. But this is different

Comment: @chadbag The singleton pattern is well known and identifiable by its trademark `[MyClass sharedInstance]` type syntax. Writing it so that `[[MyClass alloc] init]` does the same thing is **possible**, but it's a deviation from what's expected, without any real justification. It's not shorter, it's not faster, etc.

Comment: One use is where the user of the code does not need to know and does not care that there is a single instance managing whatever it is he is doing.  He just gets a new object of type `MyClass` and runs with it.   The implementor of that functionality may want to only ever allow a single instance of it (for efficiency, or ease of implementation, etc.) but the user/soncumer does not need to know or care.  I am not talking about mutable objects but rather controllers that allow access to immutable data.  Again, mostly academic vs practical.

Comment: The only time I ever did it in live code was when I provided the normal "singleton" *sharedInstance* but put the dispatch_once in the `-init` so the if someone used alloc/init they would get the same instance as was retrieved through the *sharedInstance*.  Right now I am just thinking through some problems and the best way to structure them where the code does not care that it is a singleton, but the underlying implementation is easier as it provides access to common functionality that needs to be coordinated -- with the goal of allowing easy mocks for testing.

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor  It is not a duplicate.  That stills uses the *sharedInstance* type solution.

Comment: @chadbag I didn't down vote, but your question has a bit of "can't take no as an answer" vibe to it. This *can't* be done in Swift, because Swift has made `init` conventions into language rules. E.g. initializers must initialize all members. This used to be a convention in ObjC, but is now required and compiler-enforced in Swift. This precludes the ability to implement class clusters or a singleton as you show it. Initializers... initialize. If you want more complex behaviour then that, you have static/class vars/funcs at your disposal

Comment: @Alexander Sorry it came across that way.  My previous comments were related to the Objective-C variant that you had commented on and were exclusive to that variant and your comments on it.  I was not trying to be obstinate about the Swift variation, which as has been pointed out, is not doable in the way I was looking for.

Comment: @chadbag TIL the word "obstinate". I like it!

Comment: @Paulw11  If you make an answer with this I will accept it.

Comment: @chadbag if you actually took the time to look at the answers, you could see that it provides several solutions, including an Obj-C style one.

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor   I did look at the answers.  I did not see one that behaved the way I was asking for.  The fact that it has *dispatch_once* in it does not mean it is related to what I was trying to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C an initialiser is just like any other method that is called on an instance

```
 [[alloc SomeClass] init]
```

You first `alloc` an instance and then *explicitly* invoke its initialiser.

`init` is able to return any object; returning `self` is just a convention that can be ignored in special cases, such as the one you have shown.

In Swift, `init` is special.  An initialiser is invoked *implicitly* as part of the allocation

```
let x = SomeClass()
```

A Swift `init` implicitly returns `self` (or it can return  `nil` in the case of failable initialiser that has failed).  As a result, you cannot implement a "hidden singleton" in Swift by returning some other object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something similar to what you're looking for using Objective-C's associated objects. You can see a blog post about how to use it in Swift here: http://en.swifter.tips/associated-object/

I don't really understand the purpose of this though, necessarily- I think it would be *desirable* to make a singleton *look* like a singleton.

You can technically use these associated objects to create a function that always returns the same associated object, eg, `func giveMeTheSameObjectEveryTime() -> AssociatedObjectType`, which would be similar in syntax to `init() -> AssociatedObjectType`, but I think you're getting a similar effect to a singleton, since you'll have to create some boilerplate variables to hold the association, which is quite a bit more work than a simple `static let sharedInstance` property.