# How to create a default instance object of custom class with SwiftUI

Tags: swift

I have a class ScanItem defined as follows:

```swift
class ScanItem {
    let title: String
    let content: String

    init(title: String, content: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

I often need a default object of this class. I know I can pass default value to each variable of the class, but my question is: is there a mean to create default **instance** of this class, that could be used like this:

```swift
let newScan = ScanItem.defaultInstance
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24024549/1187415

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a default instance? A scan item with an empty string title and content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static property that returns a default instance

```
extension ScanItem {
    static var defaultInstance {
        let item = ScanItem()
        item.title = "<default title>"
        item.content = "<default content>"
        
        return item
    }
)
```

Comment: Perfect ! I just had to change "static let" to "static var". Thank you !

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo.