# Swift 3: extension may not contain stored properties

Tags: json, properties, swift3, httprequest

I am trying to test some code from the Apple Swift 3 documentation (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) but I get two errors saying that "extension may not contain stored properties".

This is the code:

```
import Foundation

struct Restaurant {
enum Meal: String {
    case breakfast, lunch, dinner
}

let name: String
let location: (latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
let meals: Set<Meal>
}

extension Restaurant {
private let urlComponents: URLComponents // base URL components of the web service
private let session: URLSession // shared session for interacting with the web service

static func restaurants(matching query: String, completion: @escaping ([Restaurant]) -> Void) {
    var searchURLComponents = urlComponents
    searchURLComponents.path = "/search"
    searchURLComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query)]
    let searchURL = searchURLComponents.url!

    session.dataTask(url: searchURL, completion: { (_, _, data, _)
        var restaurants: [Restaurant] = []

        if let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            for case let result in json["results"] {
                if let restaurant = Restaurant(json: result) {
                    restaurants.append(restaurant)
                }
            }
        }

        completion(restaurants)
    }).resume()
}
}
```

I get the errors at the urlComponents line and the session line.

Comment: You can not use stored properties in extensions. But you can use a computed getter and setter like here -http://stackoverflow.com/a/26867548/2908082. By the way why are you using urlComponents and session in **Restaurant** extension?? It will be better to move it in another service layer.