# Class variables in Swift

Tags: class, swift, xcode6

I wanted to create a Swift class to store some data so I wanted to use class variables 'cause I know static variables from Java. So I wrote this code:

```
class myClass {
    class var myVar:Int = 0
}
```

But this feature isn't yet supported as the warning said then. So I wanted to ask if there's a way to do that in a nice way. I know this is kinda workin' using computed properties but actually that's not what I really want.
I would really love when someone helped me :]

Comment: use `struct` instead. Structs support static vaiables

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26567571/148357) - slightly different question but pertinent answer

Comment: @Antonio thanks for the link I didn't see that earlier - but when the class variables are supported am I allowed to use them or should I rather use structures instead?

Comment: Usage of structs is just a workaround for that limitation - as soon as class (static) properties  will be available, it's better to use them. But who know when that's gonna happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two options are to use truly global variables:

```
var myVar: Int = 0
```

or to use static variables in a struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    static var myVar:Int = 0
}
```

Either of these will have scope that is global to your project/module.

(Note that type names should be capitalized: `MyType`, not `myType`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but can I use class variables when they're supported or should I better use structures instead? P.S. I actually know about class names but I just wrote it down here and didn't think that much about the names LOL

Comment: No worries! To be honest there shouldn't be a difference - *instances* of `class` and `struct` are different in that class instances are reference types and struct instances are value types, but if you're just using the type as a repository for static vars it wouldn't matter one way or the other.