# Class initializer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In Java I can create a static initializer like:

```
static { ... }
```

In Swift I can have:

```
class MyClass {
   class var myVar:Int?
}
```

**Is it possible to create some kind of class/static var initializer in Swift?**

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567480/static-properties-in-swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a computed property accessible from the class type and you want it to be like a constant value, the best option is `static` keyword.

**Type Property Syntax**

> “For computed type properties for class types, you can use the class keyword instead to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation.” *Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. [https://itun.es/pt/jEUH0.l](https://itun.es/pt/jEUH0.l_)*

With `class` keyword a subclass can override the computed value.

---

Best solution:

```
class MyClass {

   static var myVar: Int {
        return 0
   }

}
```

Comment: You write about the class keyword but in you example there is static?

Comment: The example is about the best solution.

Comment: Yes but it is with static not class!