# Define a static variable in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, static, swift2

I want to define a static variable to hold an NSDate object in Swift 2.2. I've tried the following:

```
static var interval:NSDate
var static interval:NSDate
var interval:static NSDate
```

None are working. I've written the same thing in Objective-C with the normal:

```
static NSString* str
```

But just isn't working in Swift.

Let me be more clear, I want to use a static interval in the didUpdateLocation method for locationManager so that a function will only happen after five minutes, but the user's location will still be seen in real time.  This is how I did it in Objective C

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
static NSDate *previous; //<--- This in Swift
static int run = 0;

CLLocation *location = locations.lastObject;

if (run == 0 || [location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:previous] > 10)
{
    [_dbObj insert: location.coordinate.latitude : location.coordinate.longitude : [NSDate date] : location.timestamp];

    previous = location.timestamp;

    run++;
}

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 2*1609.34, 2*1609.34);

[[self mapView] setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

}
```

From what I gather, I would need to create a class tat contains this static NSDate variable and instantiate it in the didUpdateLocations method. Yes?
Thanks!

Comment: You can define `static` property within a class using the first syntax. But where are you trying to do this? The Objective-C `static` keyword can be used at different scopes (a global, to make it accessible only to that compilation unit; a local variable within a method implementation) that aren't permitted in Swift. You have to show us _where_ you're trying to do this for us to comment further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static properties in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567480/static-properties-in-swift)

Comment: That are function-scoped static vars, and my suggestion should work. – But why don't you make them instance variables of the enclosing class instead?

Answer (score 15):

In C,

```
static <type> <name>;
```

at the **file level** defines a variable `name` whose scope is restricted to
the same compilation unit (roughly speaking: to the same source file),
and the same applies to your Objective-C code

```
static NSString* str;
```

In Swift, you achieve the same effect with a `private` property
defined on the file level:

```
private var date = NSDate()
```

`date` is visible only in the same source file,
compare [Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5)
in the Swift blog.

---

**Function scoped** static variables are possible in Swift as well,
but you have to put them inside a struct. Example:

```
func foo() -> Int {
    struct StaticVars {
        static var counter = 0
    }
    StaticVars.counter += 1
    return StaticVars.counter
}

print(foo()) // 1
print(foo()) // 2
```

Comment: Private and static are definitely NOT the same thing.  Private only affects scope, i.e., visibility.  Static in a C-family language has many different semantics, depending on the context in which it is used.  At file scope it's similar to private, at class scope it denotes a class variable vs an instance variable, at subroutine scope it denotes a persistent non-stack based value, etc.

Comment: @DavidBerry: That's why I explicitly said "static on the file level". I did not mention "static on class scope" (nor does the question, as far as I can tell). *"At file scope it's similar to private,"* – that's exactly what I tried to explain.

Comment: I guess my point was in agreement with @rob, there's not enough info to answer the question because they say nothing about scope.  My assumption was/is actually that they're asking about function scoped...

Comment: @DavidBerry: It seems that you were right with your assumption, the question is about function-scoped static variables. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Vehicle().car = "Mercedes",  Vehicle().car, giving **Lexus** , but, let vehObj = Vehicle(); vehObj.car, giving **Mercedes** . I don't know why. Whats the diff? Can u Guide me?

Comment: @McDonal_11: Every `Vehicle()` call creates a *new instance.*

Comment: Can u pls explain clearly? I couldn't find difference.

Comment: @McDonal_11: Comments are for clarification about the current question or answer, not for arbitrary discussion. If you have a question then you should post it as a question. Don't forget a [mcve] which clearly demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems here:

- `static` or `class` members are allowed only inside a `class`, and
- `static` members need to be initialized (or be declared optional to be initialized with `nil`).

Example:

```
class Foo {
    static var dt : NSDate = NSDate()
    static var optDt : NSDate? = nil
}
```

Note that the first restriction is not present in Objective-C: you are allowed to have free-standing static variables, in addition to function-scoped static variables.