# Unable to call type method on class conforming to protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

My code is really simple.

My protocol:

```
protocol BaseEntity
{
    class func getInstance(sourceObject: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: AnyObject!) -> BaseEntity
    init()
}
```

Then in another class I have this method:

```
private func convertJSONDictionaryIntoModel(jsonDictionary : [NSObject : AnyObject], mapClass: BaseEntity.Type) -> BaseEntity
{
    let object = mapClass.getInstance(jsonDictionary, context: nil)

    return object
}
```

I got a compiler error on the first line that reads as "Accessing members of protocol type value BaseEntity.Type is unimplemented"

As far as I can tell, this is possible in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this too!  This means that the Swift programming language doesn't support class methods inside of protocols... yet.  The workaround for this seems to depend on the specific situation and there's no "you should do this instead".  If anyone has a better solution, please share!

This is also the case with class variables, however there is a [hacky workaround for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015207/class-variables-not-yet-supported)

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution to this. The only way I'm able to make it to accept it is by using generics, but generics have their own limitations too. These kind of issues make me really think that the language is incomplete. Their intent was to make things easier and more explicit... well guess what if they don't support these kind of stuff and one has to rely on some workarounds as the one you exposed, that is pretty much screwed.